# cmake and libpthread

Tags: pthreads, cmake

I'm running `RHEL 5.1` and use `gcc`.

How I tell `cmake` to add `-pthread` to compilation and linking?

Comment: Can you choose an answer for this?

Comment: Dude, you gotta choose @Manuel's as the answer.

Comment: @Ehsan thehouse's answer is way better! :-)

Answer (score 307):

@Manuel was part way there.  You can add the compiler option as well, like this:

If you have CMake 3.1.0+, [this becomes even easier](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.1.0/Modules/FindThreads.cmake#L207):

```
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(my_app PRIVATE Threads::Threads)
```

If you are using CMake 2.8.12+, you can simplify this to:

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
if(THREADS_HAVE_PTHREAD_ARG)
  target_compile_options(my_app PUBLIC "-pthread")
endif()
if(CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT)
  target_link_libraries(my_app "${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}")
endif()
```

Older CMake versions may require:

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
if(THREADS_HAVE_PTHREAD_ARG)
  set_property(TARGET my_app PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS "-pthread")
  set_property(TARGET my_app PROPERTY INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS "-pthread")
endif()
if(CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT)
  target_link_libraries(my_app "${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}")
endif()
```

If you want to use one of the first two methods with CMake 3.1+, you will need `set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)` there too.

Comment: It seems like e.g. CMake 3.0.2 won't set THREADS_HAVE_PTHREAD_ARG if pthread library was found (`NOT CMAKE_HAVE_THREADS_LIBRARY`), e.g. on Ubuntu 15.04 :(

Comment: The version given for CMake 2.8.12+ won't work as intended, because of how the code works in `/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindThreads.cmake` (eg. see here https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/trusty/main/all/cmake-data/2.8.12.2-0ubuntu3/file/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindThreads.cmake)

Basically, `THREADS_HAVE_PTHREAD_ARG` is only set if the other variations of the flag weren't found (ie. `-lpthread`, `-lpthread`, or `-lthread`)

Comment: This gives the error "Cannot specify link libraries for target "my_app" which is not built by this project." -- how do you enable it universally without having to do it individually for each target?

Comment: Is the first still the easiest way in 2020/ cmake 3.17?

Comment: What happens if you don't set the THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG flag, just find and link?

Comment: I had to use `target_link_libraries(my_app INTERFACE Threads::Threads)`

Answer (score 213):

The following should be clean (using `find_package`) and work (the find module is called `FindThreads`):

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6) 
find_package (Threads)
add_executable (myapp main.cpp ...)
target_link_libraries (myapp ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

Comment: This doesn't work when using in a CXX only project. Does anyone know a nice workaround?

Comment: @Simon a bit late but please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193785/how-to-get-cmake-to-recognize-pthread-on-ubuntu

Comment: This solution works accros Mac OS X, Centos 6 and Solaris 10.

Comment: Note that this won't [set -pthread compiler flag](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2127797/673826)

Comment: is `find_package` also the approch on windows for .dll dependencies? Because usually, you have your lib dependencies in a thirdParty directory... but cmake looks in a `IMPORTED_LOCATION` path, isn't it?

Answer (score 37):

Here is the right anwser:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(your_executable ${source_files})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( your_executable
pthread
)
```

equivalent to

```
-lpthread
```

Comment: This is equivalent. "-pthread" donates much more - at compilation it's -D_REENTRANT, at link time -lpthread. On some system at even can be more than this.

Comment: SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "... -lpthread")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "... -lpthread")

Comment: I feel like this answer directly answers the question. I agree that using the Threads find module is more portable, but it is not what was asked.

Comment: this solution bricks as soon as you change from linux to freebsd or windows.

Comment: Doesn't work, "target_link_libraries(your_executable pthread)" is how it should be written.

Comment: This is not the right answer by any means. Even if you don't like thehouse's answer, and considering this was written in 2009, it's completely non-cross platform. Use thehouse's answer - and if you don't like it then go for something like `target_link_libraries(target "$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU>:-pthread>$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang>:-pthreads>")` which is at least target-based and doesn't fail on Windows and other platforms.

Answer (score 7):

`target_compile_options` solution above is wrong, it won't link the library.

Use:

`SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE} -pthread")`

OR

`target_link_libraries(XXX PUBLIC pthread)`

OR

`set_target_properties(XXX PROPERTIES LINK_LIBRARIES -pthread)`

Comment: This is brittle/outdated.  Use `find_package(Threads)` and `target_link_libraries(my_app PRIVATE Threads::Threads)` instead.