# What's the difference between -pthread and -lpthread options of gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, pthreads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [gcc - significance of -pthread flag when compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127797/gcc-significance-of-pthread-flag-when-compiling)

Currently I am working on a multi-thread project. I found that GCC 4.4 has already supported std::thread if given -std=c++0x option. I wrote a test program test_thread.cpp as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void my_thread_func()
{
    std::cout<<"hello"<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(my_thread_func);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile and link it with

```
g++ -Wall -O2 -std=c++0x -c test_thread.cpp
g++ -Wall -O2  -o test_thread test_thread.o
```

Then I got a "Segmentation fault" error.
I read the GCC manual and found that I should add -pthread options to both compile and link. This could work for me. If I add -lpthread, this works too. I want to know the differences between these two options "-pthread" and "-lpthread", thank you.