# -lpthread option of gcc

Tags: gcc, pthreads

As I know, if I want to use pthread library in linux environment I must include pthread.h and compile the source code with -lpthread option.
But I don't understand why I should compile with -lpthread option. I think the option is redundant... because I already declared to include pthread.h header file so that gcc links pthread library. Why does gcc not link pthread library file automatically by reading #include?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127797/gcc-significance-of-pthread-flag-when-compiling, you should be using `-pthread` too.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Well **linking** and **compilation** are two separate phases.

You include the header `pthread.h` so that the compiler understands the data types & symbol names, which you use in your source files but are defined/declared in the pthread library header file.

You link to the pthread libray using `-lpthread` so that the linker can actually find those symbols in the pthread library during the linking stage.

Comment: So, why don't we have to include some library explicitly for linking when we use strcpy or printf? Is it because these are all in the C standard library and that is included by default, and anything outside that library must be explicitly linked?

Comment: @master_latch:  yes thats the precise reason.

Answer (score 6):

Having `#include <pthread.h>` in your code doesn't link in the library; it only includes the header for compilation. That allows the compiler to see the various structures, function declarations, etc. included. Having `-lpthread` actually causes the linking to be done by the linker. So the include tells the compiler what's available, and the `-lpthread` actually allows the program to call the functions within the library at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Because GCC doesn't do [auto-linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-linking) of libraries triggered by header inclusion (as opposed to MSVC, or so I've been told).

Comment: There is indeed a `#pragma` option to link in a library in MSVC, but it's very rarely used (and generally considered bad practice).

Answer (score 3):

The header file just declares what the pthread functions are and how they should be called. `-lpthread` links to the library itself, containing the actual functions.

The compiler has no idea how you're going to resolve the functions in `pthread.h`. You might want to use a static library, the one provided by the system, some compatible implementation - heck, you might implement them yourself in another source file. It's up to the linker, and doesn't concern the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

By including the header files you tell the compiler which functions he's going to see. But if these functions are in an external library, like the `pthread` functions, you need to *link* this library to your program so it can actually access those functions. That's what `-lpthread` is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Pthread.h header file is included in the posix thread program but you need
 `-lpthread` while compiling because it links it with the library of pthread
**NOTE:** `-lpthread` `-lpcap` all are the switches with gcc compiler that can link particular library in our source code. (lpthread means "link pthread" library)