# How can I link with my own pthread library

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, gcc, x86-64

I want to make some modifications to the `pthread` library used for my program. That is why I want to link with my own modified pthread library. I can take the source code in `glibc` for `pthread`, modify it and use that for my programs.

Normally you use the flag `-pthread` for linking with the original `pthread` library. How do I specify in my makefile to link with my own library.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127797/gcc-significance-of-pthread-flag-when-compiling

Answer (score 4):

Just use the -L option to specify the directory where your custom lib is present and use -l option to specify the name of your library.
For Ex:

```
-L/root/x/mylib -lmypthread
```

In this case your lib name should libmypthread.so

Refer to http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html for more details.

To ensure that the library is found for loading when you execute your program, do

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = $(LD_LIBRARY_PATH):/root/x/mylib
```

Comment: You might consider passing the `-rpath` option to the linker instead: `-Wl,-rpath $MYLIB_DIR`, if I've got the syntax right.

Answer (score 2):

`-pthread` is equivalent to `-lpthread -D_REENTRANT` with gcc/glibc. You can do the same, but with a different link argument (`-lname-of-library`).

Comment: You can confirm this is true with your particular gcc version. Use `gcc -dumpspecs | grep "%{pthread"`.

Comment: turns out you don't really need `-D_REENTRANT`, ie just `-lname-of-library` should be enough

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `-pthread`. It is an undocumented GCC option, probably for compatibility with some other (Solaris?) compilers.

The `-D_REENTRANT` definition which it `-pthread` enables is completely unnecessary in glibc; none of the headers depend on this macro for thread safety. (The last of such mechanisms were removed from the glibc headers in 1998!) Simply linking in `-lpthread` is enough to switch glibc functions to thread safe mode, and `-lpthread` can be substituted with your own library, like the other answer says.

Comment: Unfortunately, while that's the way things *should be*, it may not be correct for gcc. In theory, gcc supposedly uses a POSIX-incompatible memory model whereby it could perform optimizations that wrongly move accesses across synchronization, and you need `-pthread` or `-std=c11` to make it use the correct memory model. I've never encountered a situation where it matters but I recall reading a thread on one mailing list or on the gcc bug tracker where this was the gcc developers attitude, and it may have involved a real bug...

Comment: Oh, I recall the issue now. It's accessing memory as a larger type, and it affects bitfields. gcc ignores the declared integer type on the bitfield and often performs read/modify/write cycles with a much larger (e.g. 64 bits) load/store operation, which can be extremely dangerous if the data that happens to be adjacent to the bitfield in memory is accessed by another thread (or even a signal handler). Supposedly `-pthread` disables the behavior, and there may now be a separate `-f` option for it. Interestingly, it was the Linux *kernel* this broke.

Comment: `-pthread` isn't documented by GCC, so they are free to give it new meanings.

Answer (score 0):

Compile the library in a different name, e.g., `libmypthread.so` and put it in one of the directories contained in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (or add a new directory). Now you can use `-lmypthread` to link to your library.