# C linux pthread needs sleep to work

Tags: c, linux, gcc, pthreads

I'm writing a program in c on linux using gcc.
If I'm not using that sleep statement
it will print "thread created" 2,3 or 4 number of times randomly. Can anyone explain me this behavior?
//the following code is just a sample, i know is not really useful to create a thread just to print a string :)

```
void* makeRequest(void* arg) {
    printf("Thread created\n");
}

int main(){
   pthread_t thr[10];
   for(i=0; i<3; i++){  
       pthread_create(&thr[i], 0, makeRequest, &i);
       sleep(1);
    }
 }
```

p.s. I included pthread.h and the compile option -pthread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to other remarks,

```
 pthread_create(&thr[i], 0, makeRequest, &i);
```

is incorrect, because `i` is a local variable, so `&i` is the same pointer on all your calls to [pthread_create](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_create.html)

You generally should make the data pointer to your thread routine -here the thread routine is `makeRequest` either a static pointer, or a unique pointer (unique for each thread); in practice, make it a pointer to some `malloc`-ed memoory.

A better practice would be declare some `struct my_thread_data_st`, to uniquely allocate it in the heap with

```
struct my_thread_data_st* td = malloc(sizeof(struct my_thread_data_st));
if (!td) perror("malloc td"), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
memset (td, 0, sizeof(struct my_thread_data_st));
// fill td appropriately, then
pthread_create(&thr[i], 0, makeRequest, td);
```

Or you could have an array of e.g. `int`-s, e.g. `int num[4];`, initialize it appropriately, then `pthread_create(&thr[i], 0, makeRequest, &num[i]);`

Of course, if `td` is heap-allocated thru `malloc`, don't forget to `free` it at the appropriate time, e.g. after the thread ended (e.g. after having [pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_join.html)-ed it). You might be also interested by [Boehm's GC](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) and use `GC_malloc` instead of `malloc` (then, don't bother about freeing memory, the GC will do it).

If the threads are accessing a shared data, you should serialize access to it with some [global or static] mutex (using `pthread_mutex_lock` & `pthread_mutex_unlock`)

Don't forget to call `pthread_join` on all your threads before exiting -e.g. returning from `main`.

I suggest reading some [pthreads tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) and some book on [advanced linux programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very detailed answer. It helped me a lot the heap memory alloc. suggestion. Thanks a lot again :)

Answer (score 4):

You should join all threads that you create, ending `main` as you do exits the whole process.

Alternatively you could end your `main` with `pthread_exit`.

Comment: so the pthread join must be done after that for statement? (my program is quite complex and that "for" statement must be executed infinitely many times because it waits for client requests; when a client request exists it will create 3 threads) `while(1){for(i=0; i<3; i++){  
       pthread_create(&thr[i], 0, makeRequest, &i);
       sleep(1);
    }}`

Comment: You just have to ensure that your `main` doesn't end before any of your other threads. So, yes, the join has to be somewhere between the creation of the threads in the `for` loop and the termination of `main`.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   pthread_join(thr[i], NULL);
}
```

As you have written it, there is nothing waiting for your threads to finish before main returns and exits the whole process, killing the threads.

Answer (score 1):

**First use join:** and no need to send `&i` if you don't use it.

> print "thread created" 2,3 or 4 number of times randomly.

When main thread dies all child thread also die. so you need to wait in join.

**randomly.**: because we don't know in thread context switching which will get chance. it may be main-thread or child threads.

```
for(i=0; i<3; i++){  
       pthread_create(&thr[i], 0, makeRequest, &i);   
}

for(i=0; i<3; i++){  
       pthread_join(thr[i], NULL);
}
```

<del>**Second** use `-lpthread`  **not** -pthread</del>

```
$ gcc file.c -lpthread -o output
```

**EDITED**

`-pthread`  Adds support for multithreading with the "pthreads" library. This option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker: [Jens Gustedt comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070377/c-linux-pthread-needs-sleep-to-work/14070451#comment19452326_14070451)

[**Difference between -pthread and -lpthread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127797/gcc-significance-of-pthread-flag-when-compiling?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: thanks for -lpthread suggestion, i will read more about this
//i know I don't need to send that "i" , but as i said before this is just a sample,(the whole code has about 500 lines)

Comment: @nickNatra but i don't think `"thread created"` printed 4-times, it may be max 3-times.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, `-pthread` is the correct option for gcc. It does more than would `-lpthread`: "`-pthread`
     Adds support for multithreading with the "pthreads" library.  This
     option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker."

Comment: @JensGustedt : Oh..I doesn't know about -pthread :(. I did mistake then...But I didn't find this option in google-search.