# pthread_create() "class not declared in the scope?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have a class called pos... I am trying to poll a method from this class. I used pthread_create(pthread_t thread, pos::Pirnt_data,this);

I get an error that pos is not declared in the scope... I included the h file of pos but I don't understand. I think I am using a wrong format can somebody help me

```
#include "position.h"
#include "pthread.h"
#include "pos.h"
void position::tick(schedflags_t flags) 
{   
    if(pthread_create(&thread,NULL,pos::Print_data,this)!=0) {
        stringstream bad;
        bad << "OPIMex: Could not create listener thread: "
    }
```

this class position has method tick that runs every 1 second with the data. I am trying to poll a method Print data from the class pos but it gave me that error any ideas why ?

this is class pos.h

```
#ifndef POS_H_
#define POS_H_



#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <gps.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <strings.h>
#include <math.h>


using namespace std;
namespace herpderp {
namespace modules {



int UBX_step =0;
long data;
int UBX_class;
int UBX_id=0;
int UBX_payload_length_hi;
int UBX_payload_length_lo;
int UBX_payload_counter =0;
int ck_a;
int ck_b;
int GPS_timer;
int fd;
unsigned int UBX_buffer[35];
int payload_data;
long lat=0;
long lon=0;
long alt_MSL=0;
long iTOW=0;
long alt=0; 
unsigned long LastMS;
int UBX_Read;
vector <float> v;
fstream myfile;

int Open_port(void);
int read_tofile();
long join_4_bytes( unsigned int Buffer[]);
void parse_ubx_gps(void);
void checksum(char ubx_data);
void Print_data();
int push_data_into_vector();
int decode_gps();
int Configure_gps();
int test();
int Close_NEMA();
int Open_UBX();

  }
```

}
    #endif //POS_H_

Comment: where is the pos class?

Comment: So `Print_data` must take a `void*`.

Comment: this is just the header file you want to see the c++ file too ?

Comment: @Zeyad No, he want's to see the definition of the `class` `Pos`. That (more or less) must be in one of the header files. Or you are confused about what `class` means.

Comment: I don't understnad you, You mean the constructor ?

Comment: @Zeyad If `Pos` is actually a `class`, as you are saying, there will be code somewhere (most likely a header) that looks like `class Pos {...};` or `struct Pos {...};`. If there is not, then you are misusing the word "class".

Comment: Thanks, I just found out the problem and fixed it. :D

Answer (score 2):

`pthread_kill` is not on `pthread.`. It is on `signal.h`

```
#include <signal.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) you can provide some code snippet/additional information to help you better.

2) If you are getting linkage error, check if you have linked with -lpthread library.

Comment: [Better: use `-pthread` rather than `-lpthread`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127797/gcc-significance-of-pthread-flag-when-compiling)

Answer (score 0):

Form the pos.h it seems that there is no class called pos and you just need to call the function name:

```
 if(pthread_create(&thread,NULL,Print_data,this)!=0) {
```

Comment: It might be I will try it and tell you back

Comment: Now it gave another error invalid conversion from ‘void (*)()’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’