# SIGABRT signal received when creating a std::thread c++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, c++11, stl

I create a thread in a class member method like this:

```
void MyClass::startThread()
{
    T.reset( new std::thread( &MyClass::myThreadMethod, this ) );
}

void MyClass::myThreadMethod()
{
    // ...
}
```

where

```
// In header file
std::unique_ptr<std::thread> T;
```

When I run `MyClass::startThread()`, I receive this:

*Signal received: SIGABRT (Aborted) ...*

If I step the code, it happens in the thread constructor.

I tried to removed the `unique_ptr` like this:

```
void MyClass::startThread()
{
    std::thread* T = new std::thread( &MyClass::myThreadMethod, this );
}
```

and the same thing occurred. I use gcc 4.8.2 on NetBeans 7.4 on Linux/Kubuntu 12.04.

Someone knows what happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Mark Garcia suggestion and example, and according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127797/gcc-significance-of-pthread-flag-when-compiling) I just added `-pthread` as option to the compiler.

For an unknown reason, my other projects work correctly but I believe that it is due to Boost or Open CV that must include something that was missing from this current test.

Anyway, for the moment, it works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

This happens when an `std::thread` is destroyed without a prior call to [`std::thread::detach()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) or [`std::thread::join()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join). You should call either of the two, and what to call depends on your desired behavior.

```
void MyClass::startThread() {
    T.reset( new std::thread( &MyClass::myThreadMethod, this ) );
    T->join();  // Wait for thread to finish
}
```

or

```
void MyClass::startThread() {
    T.reset( new std::thread( &MyClass::myThreadMethod, this ) );
    T->detach();  // Leave thread on its own (do not wait for it to finish)
}
```

As a side note, you can remove your use of `std::unique_ptr` by making the `std::thread` itself a member:

```
class MyClass {
    std::thread t;
};
```

To assign `t` a thread, you can construct one and move assign it to `t`:

```
t = std::thread(&MyClass::myThreadMethod, this);
```

Comment: Hello Mark Garcia, 1) removing the unique_ptr is correct, I should have though to it before. 2) I believe it doesn't worth to start a thread if we call join() right after in the same function??? 3) even with a detach, the signal is raised in the *constructor*.

Comment: @dom_beau I've made a [test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/839988ed13bedebf) showing that the problem is solved with the use of either detach or join. For (2), of course, join is usually called for long-running actions and thus calling it immediately would make execution effectively synchronous. The above is only for demonstration. (3) You may be assigning another thread to your `std::thread`, and doing that would destroy the previous object (e.g. calling `.reset` on the `unique_ptr` that already contains an `std::thread`).

Comment: The test you made of course must work. But my code looks like yours. I will try to build your code as a spike solution to test it as soon as I will have my computer. But I must tell you that my code is mostly like yours and the SIGABRT is raised in the *constructor* of the thread, that is, before it can reach the `join()` or the `detach()`.

Comment: ...by the way, I don't have this strange behaviour when I use a static member. But in that case, I must use a "communication" structure to pass data pointers between the thread and the current object because the static member cannot access non-static data...