# C++ SIGABRT on new thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, parsing

I'm trying to parallelize a method inside a Parser class. Since this method requires shared mutex I wasn't able to use OpenMP, and therefore had to go with the standard libraries.

I'm currently working with C++ 17, and here's the main code that's not working:

```
auto p = Parser(.7);
int tMax = thread::hardware_concurrency();
vector<thread> threads;

int chunk = (int)lines.size() / tMax;
for (int i = 0; i < tMax; ++i) {
       int start = chunk * i;
       threads.emplace_back(&Parser::parse, &p,lines, start, i);
}
```

The problem is that I get a SIGABRT at the creation of a new thread and I can't figure out the reason for this.

You can find the full/messy code [here](https://pastebin.com/iAzGrH3d). In case you want to dive into it I'll leave a brief list of the important lines:

- 32-110: Auxiliary objects definitions
- 112: Start of Parser definition
- 335: **parse** method definition
- 424: **main** (referenced code at 443)

I looked for similar cases to mine (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619682/sigabrt-signal-received-when-creating-a-stdthread-c11)) but I still can't understand what is really happening and why.

Debugging only leads me to the thread constructor and into assembly code, until it reaches the terminate exception thrower.

I think I might be messing something up with address and references, since I'm passing the object itself, but I don't have enough experience with C++ to know for certain.

I should also mention that this function works perfectly when called within the main thread, but when creating the second thread it seems to throw SIGABRT.

**EDIT:**
Minimal/Cleaned Example can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/dQyMQyiV).

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: Sure, I'll edit/add the code for the example

Comment: `threads.emplace_back(&Parser::parse, &p` You're calling `parse` on the same instance from multiple threads. Are you *sure* that function is thread-safe?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I tried to make it so with mutexes, so in theory it should be.

Comment: If you don't handle an exception in a thread, `std::terminate()` is called. Add a try-catch block if you want to find out more about the exception.

Comment: Tangentially related: you're re-assigning `this->id` in every thread which will probably cause some wrong output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a `vector` of threads and then immediately exit `main` without waiting for any of them to finish execution. This will cause them to crash.

Adding `for(auto& t : threads) t.join();` to the end of main to wait on all the threads works in my test.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was it! I don't know how I missed it.