# Why am I getting undefined reference to pthread_mutexattr_settype?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries, linker-errors

I am trying to compile and link a sample file from the Novell LDAP C SDK but the link is failing due to 3 unresolved symbols in the `pthread` library.  I am using gcc 4.8.1 on Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy).  I have properly included the `pthread` library as the last library on the command line, but these particular symbols are still not being resolved.

```
$ gcc -Wl,-trace-symbol=pthread_mutexattr_settype -Wl,-trace-symbol=pthread_mutexattr_init   -Wl,-trace-symbol=pthread_mutex_trylock  -o search search.o -L../lib -lldapsdk -lpthread

../lib/libldapsdk.so: reference to pthread_mutexattr_settype<br>
../lib/libldapsdk.so: reference to pthread_mutexattr_init<br>
../lib/libldapsdk.so: reference to pthread_mutex_trylock<br>
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: definition of pthread_mutexattr_settype<br>
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: definition of pthread_mutexattr_init<br>
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: definition of pthread_mutex_trylock<br>
../lib/libldapsdk.so: undefined reference to pthread_mutexattr_settype<br>
../lib/libldapsdk.so: undefined reference to pthread_mutex_trylock<br>
../lib/libldapsdk.so: undefined reference to pthread_mutexattr_init<br>
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

$ readelf --all  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0|grep pthread_mutexattr_settype<br>
   114: 00009d90    36 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 pthread_mutexattr_settype@@GLIBC_2.1<br>
   493: 00009d90    36 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 pthread_mutexattr_settype
```

Comment: Please try passing `-pthread` to the compiler (without the `-l`). See also [gcc - significance of -pthread flag when compiling](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2127797/341970).

Comment: OK. Glad to hear it helped!

Comment: @ali: You should make this an answer.

Comment: Ali added his comment as an answer, so might like to accept it as it seems to answer your question.

Answer (score 31):

<sub>Just writing up the comment as an answer as it proved to be helpful based on other users' feedback.</sub>

---

Please pass `-pthread` to the compiler (without the `-l`). See also [gcc - significance of -pthread flag when compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2127797/341970).

Comment: Why? What's the difference between `-pthread` and `-lpthread`? 
Thanks for the solution though, it worked for me as well.

Answer (score 18):

In cmake you can add`set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -pthread " )`

Do not edit spacing!

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks :)

Comment: In my case, I used set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS " -pthread ") ... and it solved my headache. Merlin's beard !!!

Comment: I used add_compile_options(-pthread) and add_link_options(-pthread) for cmake.