# Get an error using c++ threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm making a program which change the focus of many windows by using a thread.

```
pthread_t getFocus;
pthread_create ( &getFocus, NULL, returnFocus, NULL );
pthread_join ( getFocus, NULL );

void *returnFocus ( void *argument ) {
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling, I get this error:

```
undefined reference to _imp__pthread_create 
undefined reference to _imp__pthread_join
```

What should I do to correct this error?

Comment: Add `-pthread` to your compiler/linker options

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ meant -lpthread

Comment: @jsantander: no. `-pthread` is correct and should be used both for compiling & linking (potentially sets preprocessor flags).

Comment: @jsantander As Mat said, i meant `-pthread` exactly!

Comment: @jsantander See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127797/gcc-significance-of-pthread-flag-when-compiling `-pthread` does a lot more than just `-lpthread`.

Comment: @Mat ... but just because you're in gcc

Comment: @jsantander: or clang, or icc. If you're using MSVC, then yes something different needs to be done. Same for xlC on AIX. (But `-lpthread` isn't the right thing for those two either.)

Answer (score 0):

When using using pthread you also need to link with the pthread librairy using *-lpthread* option.

```
gcc -o myprog myprog.c -lpthread
```

**EDIT:**

As Maxim said in the commentaries, the portable way to do so is:

```
gcc -o myprog myprog.c -pthread
```

*-lpthread* is the Unix way to do it (the one I learnt), but you should always use **-pthread**, and if not available (or if you have a very specific reason), use *-lpthread*.

On linux *-lpthread* mean "link with the pthread librairy", while **-pthread** just say "do w/e you need to do for pthread", from what I read.

Comment: Non-portable option. Use `-pthread` for both compiler and linker.

Comment: @Maxim Ok, didnt knew. I'm from linux environement and I always used -lpthread. (edit) And I also havn't read the commentaries. Should I delete this answer?