# gcc 4.8.2 on Linux - Simple program using thread crashes

Tags: linux, multithreading, gcc, c++11, devtoolset

I have just installed gcc 4.8.2 on Centos (I am using devtoolset-2). I wrote a very simple program using thread. It compiles fine but crashes when executed?

```
 #include <thread>
 #include <iostream>

 void test() 
 { 
   std::cout << "test\n"; 
 }

 void main()
 {
      std::thread t(test);
      t.join();
      return 0;
 }
```

I compile with:

```
 scl enable devtoolset-2 bash
 c++ -o test test.cpp -std=c++11
```

I am terribly surprised. I must do something wrong, not using the write libc++ etc? Do you have any idea how I could debug this. Thank you!
I compile it on Mac (Maverick) which obviously doesn't use gcc and it works fine.

Comment: Try adding the command line option `-pthread` -- and of course also `-Wall`.

Comment: That worked thank you so much, I didn't know on Linux you still needed to use pthread with thread? Thank you very much.

Comment: `main()` shall return `int`.

Comment: @nosid: Why not add your proposal as the answer?

Comment: I voted up the question despite of not checking the GCC docs for thread options, because it shows a nice basic test case, complete unlike most questions of this nature.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I didn't think about checking the docs indeed, but your comment is helpful and I will do it next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux, you should use the command line option `-pthread` with GCC and Clang for compiling and linking. In your case, the command line should look as follows:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pthread test.cpp -o test
```

See the following links for more information:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_concurrency.html
- [gcc - significance of -pthread flag when compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127797/gcc-significance-of-pthread-flag-when-compiling)
- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52681