# G++ can't link in some libraries, but using ld separately it finds libraries

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker

On a Ubuntu Linux machine g++ doesn't appear to be linking libraries as it should. I can't supply full source code, but essentially it is a small program which creates a pthread. It compiles fine on two other Debian machines, but on the Ubuntu machine it complains about an undefined reference to pthread_create.

The command line is something like this:

```
g++ -I. -lpthread source_code.cpp -o program
```

To debug this I ran g++ under strace to see how it was looking for libpthread. When I did that, I did not see ANY references to libpthread. It was as if the linker wasn't even trying to search for the library. On the machines that did compile I saw several calls to open() when it searched the filesystem for the library.

When I ran ld separately it seems to find libpthread without a problem, and the strace output confirms that it is searching for the library as it should. I ran ld separately like this:

```
user@machine:~/src$ ld -lpthread
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
```

Why could cause g++ to not search the filesystem correctly for libraries when ld seems to do so just fine by itself? Kinda stumped on this one at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: Linking is order dependent. Did you try putting `-lpthread` at the END if your compile line?

Comment: @FredLarson That seemed to be the trick. I knew that linker order matter under certain situations, but this one threw me for a loop. Apparently its a part of an actual effort to implement more strict behavior in GCC. Can you add an answer that I can accept? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I think @Slava gave a better answer. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2127797/10077

Answer (score 1):

For enabling multithreading in gcc you should pass `-pthread` flag not `-lpthread` -

> -pthread
>
> ```
>        Add support for multithreading using the POSIX threads library.                
>        This option sets flags for both
>        the preprocessor and linker.  
>        It does not affect the thread safety of object code produced by the
>        compiler or that of libraries supplied with it.
> ```

Comment: Why not just link the library directly? Is there any rationale for this?

Comment: @Mr.Shickadance because `-pthreads` not only links library but also set flags for the preprocessor so some library headers may compile differently.