# Segmentation fault (core dump) error when creating thread from member function

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, segmentation-fault

Does anyone know why this causes a segmentation error?

```
int main ()
{
    udp_client *client = new udp_client("192.168.160.128", 2500);
    client->mysetsockopt("af");
    client->askForFileAndID();
    client->getFileSize();

//this line causes the seg fault error
    std::thread t1(&udp_client::sendFiletoServer, client);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure: Are you using `-pthread` when compiling?

Comment: i have <thread> in my includes. do i need to add -pthread flag during compilation?

Comment: If you're using GCC on linux, yes, you do. the standard threads library depends on it.

Answer (score 2):

Segmentation error can occurred only at runtime, if you have segmentation error, you compiled and linked your program. Probably the problem is that your program finished execution after creating the `thread`. Try to join your `thread` t1.

Add:
`t1.join();`

before return from main.

Comment: When missing the flag -pthread on compilation, the program will compile fine, but will generate runtime errors. You can try it yourself. I agree, though, he also should join the thread.

Comment: `-pthread` is not used in compile process, that is the reason why you can compile your code, it is used in linking process. Linker will fail without `-pthread`. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: `-pthread` is not a linking flag. It does add `-lpthread` to the linking process, but it also does some other things on some systems(i.e.: Marking files as reentrant is one example). As I said, missing this flag will not cause a failure on compilation (nor on linking), but will generate a bad program. This is probably because without `-pthread`, some headers will not use symbols from the pthreads library, and therefore need not be linked to it. They will, however, miss some important changes on how they need to work, making them not thread-safe.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127797/gcc-significance-of-pthread-flag-when-compiling

Comment: i added t1.join in the code and -pthread in Project Properties>Settings>Cross G++ Compiler>>Miscellaneous>Other flags, however i still get the error. I will try using pthread instead of std::thread and will post here the result. thanks everyone.

Comment: changed my code to use fork instead. couldnt make the other options work. thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link with pthreads. To acomplish this, just add `-pthread` to your compilation flags.

Beware that if you want to link statically (bad idea), you'll also need to add some other stuff. Namely: `-Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive`

Check https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52590