# Why implicit declaration of pthread_yield with -lpthread while all ok with -pthread?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, pthreads

I compile this code main.c in CentOS7 with gcc:

```
#include <pthread.h>
void* mystart(void* arg)
{
    pthread_yield();
    return(0);
}
int main(void)
{
    pthread_t pid;
    pthread_create(&pid, 0, mystart, 0);
    return(0);
}
```

1st compile: `gcc -Wall -g main.c -pthread -o a.out`
It's all OK.

2nd compile: `gcc -Wall -g main.c -lpthread -o a.out`
Gives

> warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_yield' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

1. Can the 2nd `a.out` still run correctly ?
2. How to fix the warning without `-pthread`? Is `sched_yield` another way to yield a pthread ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127797/gcc-significance-of-pthread-flag-when-compiling

Comment: "*How to fix the warning without `-pthread`?*" provide the missing prototype yoursself.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on CentOS 7, both gives the warning here.

Answer (score 9):

`pthread_yield()` is a non-standard function which is typically enabled by defining

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

While you should use `-pthread` for compiling, I would expect you to get the same warning with *both* compilations (unless `-pthread` defines `_GNU_SOURCE` which may be the case).

The correct way to fix is to *not* use the non-standard function `pthread_yield()` and use the POSIX function [`sched_yield()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//functions/sched_yield.html) instead by including `#include <sched.h>`.

Comment: Only difference -pthread makes on linux is it adds a `#define _REENTRANT 1`

Comment: That's the only difference I see as well. But OP reports he does not get the warning with `-pthread` which I find odd.

Comment: It's my mistake, it's true that both -pthread and -lpthread will generate the warning 'implicit of pthread_yield'.

Comment: @zhaochenyou Right. Thanks for the confirmation. That's what I expected. So you can either define `_GNU_SOURCE` before including any headers if you want to use the non-standard function `pthread_yield()`. Or better yet, use `sched_yield()`.

Answer (score 5):

You *should* use `-pthread` for compile and link. It not only links the library, it also sets preprocessor defines and sometimes selects a different runtime library (on Windows for example).

Comment: my 2nd question is the difference between: pthread_yield and sched_yield. are they behave the same?

Comment: @zhaochenyou: One question per question. That is the rule. Also, it is the only way you get your questions correctly answered.