# CMake: add dependency to IMPORTED library

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a vendor supplied library archive which I have imported into my project:

```
add_library(
    lib_foo 
    STATIC 
    IMPORTED GLOBAL
    )

set_target_properties(
    lib_foo 
    PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION             
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/vendor/foo.a"
    )

set_target_properties(
    lib_foo 
    PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES 
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/vendor"
    )
```

When I try to link an application using this library, I get `undefined reference to 'pthread_atfork'` linker errors:

```
/usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.a(libtcmalloc_minimal_internal_la-static_vars.o):
    In function `SetupAtForkLocksHandler':
    /tmp/gperftools-2.4/src/static_vars.cc:119: 
        undefined reference to `pthread_atfork'
        ../vendor/foo.a(platformLib.o): In function `foo::Thread::Impl::join()':
```

So `vendor/foo.a` has a dependency on `pthread`.

I tried `target_link_libraries(lib_foo pthread)` but that doesn't work because `lib_foo` is an *IMPORTED* target, rather than a built target

> ```
> CMake Error at libfoo/CMakeLists.txt:41 (target_link_libraries):
>   Attempt to add link library "pthread" to target "lib_foo"
>   which is not built in this directory.
> ```

### Question:

**How do I link `pthread` to `lib_foo`, or specify that targets with a dependency on `lib_foo` also have a dependency on pthread?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES:

There is an additional target property you can set, [IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES.html)

> Transitive link interface of an `IMPORTED` target.
>
> Set this to the list of libraries whose interface is included when an
>   `IMPORTED` library target is linked to another target.
>
> The libraries will be included on the link line for the target.
>
> Unlike the `LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES` property, this property applies to all imported target types, including `STATIC` libraries.

```
set_target_properties(lib_foo 
    PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES 
    pthread
    )
```

### -pthread Compiler Flag:

However, in this **particular case**, `pthread` linking issues, the problem would likely be solved by adding `-pthread` to your compiler flags

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread" )
```

From `man gcc`:

> `-pthread` Adds support for multithreading with the pthreads library. This option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker.

It causes files to be compiled with `-D_REENTRANT`, and linked with -`lpthread`. On other platforms, this could differ. Use `-pthread` for most portability.

[See this question for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127797/gcc-significance-of-pthread-flag-when-compiling)

Comment: In CMake 3.14 `This property is deprecated. Use INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES instead.`.