# Android: Linking to prebuilt static libraries

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, static-libraries

I have compiled some static and shared libraries for Android. Specifically, I have the libraries

```
libcoinblas.a   libcoinlapack.a   libcoinmetis.a   libcoinmumps.a   libipopt.a
libcoinblas.so  libcoinlapack.so  libcoinmetis.so  libcoinmumps.so  libipopt.so
```

Furthermore, these libraries are inter-dependent, that is,

```
Lapack requires Blas
Mumps  requires Blas and Metis
Ipopt  requires Mumps, Metis, and Lapack
```

The Android project correctly links and runs when using the shared libraries, but fails to build with the static libraries.

In the shared case, I am using the cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( native-lib
             SHARED
             src/main/cpp/cpp_example.cpp
             src/main/cpp/MyNLP.cpp)

# Add dependent libraries
add_library(blas SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET blas PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcoinblas.so)

add_library(lapack SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET lapack PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcoinlapack.so)

add_library(metis SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET metis PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcoinmetis.so)

add_library(mumps SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET mumps PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcoinmumps.so)

add_library(ipopt SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET ipopt PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libipopt.so)

# Location of header files
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/include
                    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/include/ThirdParty)

target_link_libraries( native-lib

                       blas
                       lapack
                       metis
                       mumps
                       ipopt
                       )
```

and in the static case

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( native-lib
             SHARED
             src/main/cpp/cpp_example.cpp
             src/main/cpp/MyNLP.cpp)

# Add dependent libraries
add_library(blas STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET blas PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcoinblas.a)

add_library(lapack STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET lapack PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcoinlapack.a)

add_library(metis STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET metis PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcoinmetis.a)

add_library(mumps STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET mumps PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcoinmumps.a)

add_library(ipopt STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET ipopt PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libipopt.a)

# Location of header files
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/include
                    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/include/ThirdParty)

target_link_libraries( native-lib

                       blas
                       lapack
                       metis
                       mumps
                       ipopt
                       )
```

I presumed that I simply need to change how the libraries are added from

```
add_library(libxxx SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET libxxx PROPERTY ... libxxx.so)
```

to

```
add_library(libxxx STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET libxxx PROPERTY ... libxxx.a)
```

But that does not work. Specifically, in the static case, I get a bunch (hundreds) of

```
undefined reference to xxx
```

errors. For example,

```
../../../../libs/arm64-v8a/libipopt.a(IpLapack.o): In function `Ipopt::IpLapackDppsv(int, int, double const*, double*, int, int&)':
IpLapack.cpp:(.text+0x3d4): undefined reference to `dppsv_'
```

Although the errors are not just due to missing Lapack functions, but also Mumps and others.

---

### EDIT

Looking at the specific failed command, I believe that the libraries were specified in the correct order:

> FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . && clang++.exe 
>   --target=aarch64-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=C:/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64
>   --sysroot=sysroot -fPIC -isystem C:/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android
>   -D__ANDROID_API__=23 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a --sysroot C:/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-23/arch-arm64
>   -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o ........\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\arm64-v8a\libnative-lib.so
>   CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/cpp_example.cpp.o
>   CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/MyNLP.cpp.o  libcoinblas.a
>   libcoinlapack.a libcoinmetis.a libcoinmumps.a libipopt.a -latomic -lm
>   "C:/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/arm64-v8a/libgnustl_static.a"
>   && cd ."

Note that I sanitized the paths a little bit above so that they are slightly readable, but towards the end you can see that the libraries are listed in the order

```
libcoinblas.a libcoinlapack.a libcoinmetis.a libcoinmumps.a libipopt.a
```

---

### EDIT

I also tried changing the link command from `target_link_library` to `link_library`:

```
link_libraries(native-lib blas lapack metis mumps ipopt)
```

but this also fails. For some reason, in this case, the link command doesn't even include the libraries that it is supposed to link:

> FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . &&
>   C:\Android\android-sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe
>   --target=aarch64-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=C:/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64
>   --sysroot=C:/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem C:/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android
>   -D__ANDROID_API__=23 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a --sysroot C:/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-23/arch-arm64
>   -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o ........\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\arm64-v8a\libnative-lib.so
>   CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/cpp_example.cpp.o
>   CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/MyNLP.cpp.o  -latomic -lm
>   "C:/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/arm64-v8a/libgnustl_static.a"
>   && cd ." CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/cpp_example.cpp.o: In
>   function `Java_io_jeti_ipopt_1static_MainActivity_stringFromJNI':

Comment: How did you build `Lapack` as a shared library in the first place? I guess when you did you had to somehow specify its dependency on `Blas`. For the static libraries the linking step has not "happened" yet, so you have to explicitly specify the various dependencies in the CMakeFile. Not 100% sure, but give that a try.

Comment: Can you get to see the generated linker line, if so check the libraries are present in the correct order: least dependant 1st.

Comment: I built some Android standalone toolchains with gfortran here: https://github.com/jeti/android_fortran

Comment: Hopefully they will be useful to others.

Comment: Then I built ipopt (and blas, lapack etc.). I put the build script here: https://github.com/jeti/android_ipopt

Comment: To avoid having to run the build scripts yourself, I put the compiled files in the `releases` section of each repo

Comment: So, for instance, in the release section of https://github.com/jeti/android_ipopt, I have the shared and static libraries mentioned above for some common Android architectures.

Comment: As for the topic at hand, I will update the question to show variations that I have tried.

Comment: Where you say `and in the static case` should you not be using **STATIC** *instead* of **SHARED** ? *i.e.* `add_library( native-lib STATIC src/main/cpp/cpp_example.cpp src/main/cpp/MyNLP.cpp)`

Comment: I was under the impression that the Android library itself always had to be shared. Anyways, I will test either today or tomorrow with this change...

Comment: Here is a classic case where a minimal example, demonstration the problem, should be helpful to you and us, and should be easy to construct.

Comment: @JonGoodwin You are right. It's a shame that questions with bounties cannot be close-voted. I don't get how is upvoting such useless (for other people) questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your libraries are interdependent:

```
Lapack requires Blas
Mumps  requires Blas and Metis
Ipopt  requires Mumps, Metis, and Lapack
```

This means that the order for linking them should be reverse:

```
ipopt
mumps
metis
lapack
blas
```

If you don't want to waste your time on figuring out the best order, but rather let the linker to find out (this may [slow your builds significantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791152/android-linking-to-prebuilt-static-libraries/49842064?noredirect=1#comment87688995_49842064)), you can use

[target_link_libraries(native-lib -Wl,--start-group
                       blas
                       lapack
                       metis
                       mumps
                       ipopt
                       -Wl,--end-group)](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/545#issuecomment-337215908).

You can also teach CMake about the dependencies between imported static libs, via [IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36922782/192373), e.g.

```
set_target_properties(lapack 
  PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES 
  blas)
```

and so on.

This will translate

```
target_link_libraries( native-lib
                   blas
                   lapack
                   )
```

To

```
clang++ -o libnative-lib.so … libblas.a libnlapack.a libblas.a
```

Comment: If CMake knows the dependencies, you don't have to provide the order, CMake will figure it out by itself.

Comment: @usr1234567 apparently, this didn't happen for the TS in this case.

Comment: Your answer does not answer the question and is IMHO a bad advice. OP should reduce the question and provide a minimal working example. Then we can work out a proper solution.

Comment: It seems like ordering was indeed the problem. Now it is complaining about missing gfortran in the toolchain, which makes sense since that is a dependency which I forgot to include, and which is not in the default NDK toolchain. Repacking the libraries with that will take a lot of time, so I am tentatively marking this as the answer.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but if you could build the **.so** versions of these libs, you must have **libgfortran.a** somewhere, and only add it as a dependency following the same pattern as above.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. For some of the Android architectures, I see one (mips) or several (arm). But for others, I don't see one (x86). I have to revisit my build script for gfortran. Maybe i did something strange there

Comment: FYI, using start-group/end-group can be pretty bad for build speed.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be anything to do with libraries at all.  It could be to do with the way that dppsv () is prototyped.

The source file corresponding to the linker error you quote in your post is here:

https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt/blob/master/Ipopt/src/LinAlg/IpLapack.cpp

And this contains the following code snippet:

```
extern "C" {

/** LAPACK Fortran subroutine DPPSV. */
void F77_FUNC(dppsv,DPPSV)(char *uplo, ipfint *n,
                           ipfint *nrhs, const double *A,
                           double *B, ipfint *ldB, ipfint *info);
}
```

The F77_FUNC macro is evidently designed to map to the function naming convention used by whatever Fortran compiler you happen to be using, see here:

https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt/blob/master/Ipopt/src/Common/IpoptConfig.h

Now this is not my area of expertise but it could well be that this macro is not doing the right thing in your case.  You can run **nm** on the relevant .o file produced by the Fortran compiler to see what it is generating with your particular build setup.  If it's not **dppsv_** then you know what's wrong.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the input, but there are hundreds of linking errors that reference different libraries. For instance, some errors are complaining of missing Lapack functions, some are missing mumps functions, etc. I think Alex is correct, but I need to generate some more files to verify that he is correct, and that will take a few days

Comment: OK, good luck.  An old-school trick which probably still works is to name  libraries twice (or more) in the command line passed to the linker.

Comment: Definitely naming the libs twice works, but CMake is too smart, you need some special ways (described above) to convince it to use this trick. But as long as the static libs don't have circular dependencies, the most natural way to is list them in reverse order.