# Issue with std::thread from c++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, g++, std, stdthread

I have some troubles trying to compile a program with multi-threading from the standard template library.
It return me a obscure error when i try to compile the following program :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Thread 1\n";
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::thread tr(foo);
    std::cout << "Main thread\n";
    tr.join();

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand the error :

```
/tmp/ccE8EtL1.o : In the function « std::thread::thread<void (&)()>(void (&)()) » :
 file.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6threadC2IRFvvEJEEEOT_DpOT0_[_ZNSt6threadC5IRFvvEJEEEOT_DpOT0_]+0x21) : undefined reference to « pthread_create »
  collect2: error : ld has return 1 execution status code
```

I compile it with :

> g++ -std=c++14 file.cpp -o test -Wall

Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pass `-pthread` to the compiler. [This flag combines what is necessary to compile and link the pthread library (`-lpthread` is not always enough)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-pthread-1107). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2127797/1171191).

Comment: Thank you, it was the solution \o/

Comment: For completeness: [g++ - Why do I have to pass “-pthread” option while using std::thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46994982/g-why-do-i-have-to-pass-pthread-option-while-using-stdthread)