# g++ - Why do I have to pass "-pthread" option while using std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, g++, pthreads

I'm just trying to understand a concept used by g++. Here my very simple std::thread application:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void func() {
    std::cout << "Running..." <<  std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(func);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm able to compile it on macOs/Xcode 9.0 setup with following command:

> g++ main.cpp -std=c++11

But I'm unable to compile it on Linux with the same command, as far as I know I have to pass `-pthread` option too. Otherwise it gives me following error:

*gcc version 7.1.1 20170622 (Red Hat 7.1.1-3)*

```
main.o: In function `std::thread::thread<void (&)()>(void (&)())':
/usr/include/c++/5/thread:137: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
```

I think it's illogical and I shouldn't even know that it's implementing the std::thread class via pthread. Why do I have to pass `-pthread` option and link against pthread library? Isn't C++11 supposed to abstract me away from platform specific details? Or do I have any other alternative libraries such as pthread that I can link against for my std::thread usage? Or should I report that as a bug?

Thanks.

Comment: Using a modern version of GCC you shouldn't need to do this - what is your GCC version?

Comment: c++11 or any other version does not specify how you interact with the compler/tools. You'll just have to accept that on some platforms, you need to invoke the compiler with certain flags when you need certain features.

Comment: @NeilButterworth gcc version 7.1.1 20170622 (Red Hat 7.1.1-3)

Comment: "Isn't C++11 supposed to abstract me away from platform specific details" C++11 abstracts your *code* away from platform specific details, which means that if you follow the rules your sources will be trivially compilable with any other conforming compiler; the build system remains ugly as always.

Comment: @MatteoItalia The compiler should be responsible for propagating library dependencies of its own implementation details. I ran into the same thing on GCC 8.3 on RHEL7: now I have to guess at my compiler's implementation and link additional libraries accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649828/what-are-the-correct-link-options-to-use-stdthread-in-gcc-under-linux ?

Answer (score 2):

According to [GCC's concurrency page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/libstdc++/manual/manual/using_concurrency.html), it's necessary to provide additional options to the compiler based on the features being used. You can verify that your version of GCC's threads rely on POSIX threads:

```
$ gcc -v 2>&1 | grep "Thread model"
Thread model: posix
```

See [this bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52681) for a justification for the behavior:

> The problem is that not all targets need -pthread, or some which do need it spell it differently, and not all platforms define _REENTRANT when the option is used, so there's no reliable way to do what you're asking for.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question IMHO. The standard library should not require you to specify any other libraries to link against.

Answer (score 2):

I am moving `pthread` to `std:thread` in C++11 and have encountered the same phenomenon you've been met, and I found this artical -- it may be the proper answer: https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/12/17/why-glibc-234-removed-libpthread#

A quick conclusion: It depends on the version of `glibc`. `glibc` with versions prior to `2.34` will require the `-lpthead` flag even the code does not use `pthread` explicitly.

To check the version of `glibc` we can use `ldd --version` command, on my Ubuntu 20.04, it returns like this: `ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.9) 2.31`, so I still have to add the `-lpthread` flag to `use std:thread`.

Answer (score 0):

`pthread` is an industry standard over the OS specific threads, using the OS specific calls.

`std::thread` is an abstraction in C++ that could be implemented using `pthread` or the OS's native threads. But to make it work on as many OS's as possible fast the `std-library` implementer could just implement it in `posix` as they should be good to go on all compliant OS's.

There are exceptions, some windows only `std-library` uses windows native threads instead.

Comment: That's all fine, but why should the user have to link against anything explicitly when only using standard library constructs? It's GCC's linker's business to sort out what to link against, so that everything in the standard library can be used.

Comment: @einpoklum But the linker doesn't know your using std, your program could have been some fortran program that is being linked or it could already be included in one of the libs your including so extra work to find out what. Or you could wish to use another thread library to link against. It would be nice if the linker could read my mind and then link what I was thinking, but we have to wait a bit more for that.

Comment: But my program didn't come from Fortran. I was using g++ for compiling and for linking. At least when that's the case, it should make sure the linker is referred to the appropriate libraries.