# two unique_lock a same mutex performs differently with/without compile option -pthread

Tags: pthreads, mutex

Source code in `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::mutex mtx;

    std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;

    std::unique_lock ulk1(mtx);
    std::unique_lock ulk2(mtx);

    std::cout << "End" << std::endl;
}
```

When compilation arguments are:

`g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o main`

Console prints:

```
Start
End
```

While compilation arguments are:

`g++ -std=c++17 -pthread main.cpp -o main`

Console prints:

```
Start
```

Program is blocking here...

Why option `-pthread` causes this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [g++ - Why do I have to pass "-pthread" option while using std::thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46994982/g-why-do-i-have-to-pass-pthread-option-while-using-stdthread)

Comment: That's about `std::thread`, but the same applies to all GNU C++ classes that are implemented on top of pthreads, definitely including its version of `std::mutex`.