# Multithreading flag in gcc

Tags: multithreading, gcc, g++, pthreads, travis-ci

I was trying to compile some multithreading code on different `gcc` versions on `travis-ci`. The versions that were used for the build were: `g++ 4.8` and `g++ 4.9`. The code would refuse to compile without `-lpthread` on both versions. On adding the `-lpthread` flag however, they would compile, but when run, the `g++ 4.8` code just crashed, while `g++ 4.9` seemed to have build the right compilation. Now, when I changed the flag to `-pthread` on both compilers, both built correctly. I understand, `-lpthread` links with the `C-style` thread library, while `-pthread` causes the compiler to link the correct library, which 'might' not be the `C-style` thread library. Am I correct? Here's the link to the two build-logs: [gcc 4.8](https://travis-ci.org/sauvik3/Matrix/jobs/259246080) and [gcc 4.9](https://travis-ci.org/sauvik3/Matrix/jobs/259246083).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gcc - significance of -pthread flag when compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127797/gcc-significance-of-pthread-flag-when-compiling)

Comment: Exact duplicate! :) Thanks!