# CMake : FIND_PACKAGE(Threads) for Android cross-compilation

Tags: android, pthreads, cmake, android-ndk

I'm using the Android NDK and Cmake to generate shared libraries of my project.

I'm porting an existing project from Ubuntu to Android, and right now I need to port some executables files. I compile successfully all the executable file sexecpt one which needs the `Threads` library.

In CMakeList.txt, there is `FIND_PACKAGE(Threads)` which finds the library while compiling for Ubuntu, but not for Android.

I followed this [cmake and libpthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620918/cmake-and-libpthread) but with no success.

I think I should write the `FindThread.cmake` file but I'm pretty new to CMake and don't really know how to do it, especially as I don't know where is located the thread library for Android.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: did you find a solution to this? FindThread.cmake seems to ignore CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write your own FindThread.cmake. On a standard linux installation, it can be found within /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/ .

Check where this Modules/ directory might be installed on your platform.

Answer (score 2):

Under Android, there is no need for `FIND_PACKAGE(Threads)` because the Android libc standard library (called "bionic") already includes the relevant functions in [`threads.h`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/include/threads.h) and [`pthread.h`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/docs/status.md). That support is not yet completely POSIX compliant and [differs by API level](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/docs/status.md), but will be sufficient for most cases.

So you can just skip over finding and linking to an external threads library. If your CMake file is meant for cross-platform use, it would look like this:

```
set(CMAKE_THREAD_PREFER_PTHREAD TRUE)
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG TRUE)

if(NOT CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Android")
    find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries (your-target-name PRIVATE Threads::Threads)
endif()
```

Comment: While this solution works, it is not the most elegant way to do it. KDE ECM ("Extra CMake Modules") implemented a more idiomatic solution for this that simulates having found the Threads library when on Android. You can check their source. Still need to find it again and quote it in my answer.