# CMake FindThreads.cmake won't find my pthreads.h header

Tags: android, cmake

I'm using [android-cmake](http://code.google.com/p/android-cmake/) to compile an application for Android. This essentially creates a CMake toolchain file for using the toolchain provided with Android's NDK.

As with [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990661/cmake-find-packagethreads-for-android-cross-compilation), I'm having problems with the following line in my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
```

The header file is located at

```
~/Android/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/pthread.h
```

The library file is located at

```
~/Android/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib/libthread_db.so
```

The problem is that FindThreads.cmake calls `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES("pthread.h", CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H)` and this seems to not bother to check in that directory.

According to [CMake's Useful Variables wiki page](http://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables#Environment_Variables) `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` allows the setting of the header search path, `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH` allows setting of the library search path, and `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` seems provide both for find_package.

However, despite whether I set environment variables before running cmake...

```
export CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=~/Android/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr:~/Android/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include
```

... or whether I set them directly in CMakeLists.txt...

```
if(ANDROID)
    set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH
        ${ANDROID_NDK_SYSROOT}/usr
        ${ANDROID_NDK_SYSROOT}/usr/include
        ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH}
    )

    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH
        ${ANDROID_NDK_SYSROOT}/usr
        ${ANDROID_NDK_SYSROOT}/usr/lib
        ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH})

    set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
        ${ANDROID_NDK_SYSROOT}
        ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})

    message(${ANDROID_NDK_SYSROOT})
    message(${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH})

endif()

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
```

... (and this does get executed, the messages are printed), and where `${ANDROID_NDK_SYSROOT}` contains

```
/Users/martin/Android/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-8/arch-arm
```

I still get the message

> Could NOT find Threads (missing: Threads_FOUND)

Does anybody have any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem after a lot of debugging and it's quite strange. Essentially, FindThreads.cmake calls a macro called `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES` which tries to  `TRY_COMPILE` a source file which simply includes the headers that the `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES` macro is provided with.

Note that it does use `CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES` as suggested by @sakra so that's useful.

Using android-cmake, the `TRY_COMPILE` macro tries to compile with the arm-linux-androideabi-gcc compiler from the NDK with all of the specified compile flags. The android.toolchain.cmake file contains the following lines that set some of these compile flags:

```
if( BUILD_WITH_ANDROID_NDK )
 set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "--sysroot=\"${ANDROID_NDK_SYSROOT}\" ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}" )
 set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "--sysroot=\"${ANDROID_NDK_SYSROOT}\" ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}" )
```

The TRY_COMPILE macro fails and as per the CMakeError.log file contains the following:

```
Run Build Command:/opt/local/bin/gmake "cmTryCompileExec/fast"
/opt/local/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/Users/martin/Repositories/Delta/build/android/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
"/Applications/CMake 2.8-4.app/Contents/bin/cmake" -E cmake_progress_report /Users/martin/Repositories/Delta/build/android/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/CheckIncludeFiles.c.o
/Users/martin/Android/android-ndk-r7/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc   --sysroot=;/Users/martin/Android/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-8/arch-arm" -fPIC -DANDROID -Wno-psabi -fsigned-char -mthumb -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp  " -I/Users/martin/Android/android-ndk-r7/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include -I/Users/martin/Android/android-ndk-r7/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -I/Users/martin/Android/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr -I/Users/martin/Android/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/CheckIncludeFiles.c.o   -c /Users/martin/Repositories/Delta/build/android/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFiles.c
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: no input files
```

If you scroll to the right on the actual compiler line (second from the bottom) you can see the `--sysroot=;/...` section. Even though the CMake lines above use escaped strings, CMake has turned this first escaped quotation into a semicolon and left the second as a normal quotation, resulting in a semicolon in the sysroot line and then a string literal containing all the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS afterwards (easy to see with SO's syntax highlighting).

The solution to this is to modify android.toolchain.cmake to remove the escaped quotations as they are unnecessary.

```
if( BUILD_WITH_ANDROID_NDK )
 set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "--sysroot=${ANDROID_NDK_SYSROOT} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}" )
 set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "--sysroot=${ANDROID_NDK_SYSROOT} ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}" )
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` will only affect the CMake [`find_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_file.html) and [`find_path`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_path.html) commands. The `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES` function called by FindThreads.cmake does not honor that variable. For `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES` you can set the variable `CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES` instead:

```
set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES 
  ${ANDROID_NDK_SYSROOT}/usr 
  ${ANDROID_NDK_SYSROOT}/usr/include)
```

Comment: From further reading of FindThreads.cmake this answer is logical, but it still doesn't fix my problem for some reason. Threads_FOUND is still not being set. Will try to debug more and update my question when I find the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I am on CMake `3.18.1-g262b901`, NDK `21.4.7075529`, Android Studio `2020.3.1`.

This issue is showing up, as you likely know, because android includes `pthread.h` in libc++, so there is no package for pthread. The `FindThreads.cmake` file which `find_package(Threads REQUIRED)` uses does attempt to account for such things [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/63a65baf4c343c73b2142078ef0045d3711dea1d/Modules/FindThreads.cmake#L141-145) by attempting to compile a program with `#include "pthread.h"` and on success will pretend it found a package.

**So why is it failing?** In my environment, after investigating the `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE` macro I found it was failing with the following error

```
error: invalid argument '-std=c++11' not allowed with 'C'
```

It seems the android studio environment was setting this flag to the compiler, even for C code.

**What fixes it?**

Adding the following code around the failing call to set `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_LOADED` to false while `find_package(Threads REQUIRED)` is evaluating should make `FindThreads.cmake` use `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX` instead of the C version.

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_LOADED 0)

#Your failing instruction

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_LOADED 1)
```

**NOTE:** You could always not make the `find_package(Threads REQUIRED)` call in the first place if you have access to the CMake files which are causing the error. An `#include "pthread.h"` call should work just fine in the android environment without any extra assertions.

**Curiously...** The following evaluates to true on my top level `CMakeLists.txt`. Someone smarter than I might want that information.

```
include(CheckIncludeFile)
CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE("pthread.h" TEST)
message("TEST: ${TEST}")
```