# CMake with iOS Toolchain: Can't Find Threads

Tags: ios, cmake

I'm trying to use [ios-cmake](http://code.google.com/p/ios-cmake/) to generate Xcode project targeting iOS. However, it cannot find Threads. Here's a simple CMake script for demonstration:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED (VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT (MyCITest)

SET (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules")

########################
# EDIT: I've also tried adding the lines below prior to posting this question, 
# but there doesn't seem to be any effect.
# (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386897)

SET (CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES ${CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT}/usr ${CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT}/usr/include)
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "--sysroot=${CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "--sysroot=${CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT} ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")

########################

FIND_PACKAGE (ZLIB REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE (LibXml2 REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE (Threads REQUIRED)
```

Running CMake from the terminal:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../cmake/toolchains/iOS.cmake -GXcode
```

This is the output I got:

```
-- Toolchain using default iOS SDK: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk
-- Found ZLIB: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libz.dylib (found version "1.2.5") 
-- Found LibXml2: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib (found version "2.7.8") 
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - not found
CMake Error at cmake/modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find Threads (missing: Threads_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:288 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/modules/FindThreads.cmake:166 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I've already triple-checked that pthread.h is located in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/include`, and besides, it located ZLib and LibXML2 without a problem, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
> cmake --version
cmake version 2.8.10.2
```

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/q/8386897/424459 ?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the iOS toolchain currently doesn't support `TRY_COMPILE`, which is used by `CheckIncludeFiles.cmake`, which is in turn used by `FindThreads.cmake`. The toolchain is currently set to skip `TRY_COMPILE` by using:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)
set (CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)
```

Reference: http://code.google.com/p/ios-cmake/issues/detail?id=1&can=1

Comment: This workaround will work, however, the fact that the toolchain "doesn't support" try_compile isn't quite accurate. The issue is with the xcode generator which will try to sign the try_compile project, which will fail, resulting in find threads missing. I'd say it's more try_compile that doesn't support the ios toolchain because of signing issues.

Answer (score 12):

None of these solutions seem to work.  I found the only thing that consistently worked for me was to set the variables that FindThreads.cmake sets. In other words, define the following in your toolchain file:

```
set(CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT "-lpthread")
set(CMAKE_HAVE_THREADS_LIBRARY 1)
set(CMAKE_USE_WIN32_THREADS_INIT 0)
set(CMAKE_USE_PTHREADS_INIT 1)
```

Comment: This will work, but it basically overrides the actual process of finding pthread: this is the equivalent of hardcoding it, which isn't inaccurate but maybe will cause problems with future updates and scaling.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is indeed due to the call to `try_compile` failing in FindThreads.cmake. But for me setting `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS` was not enough. Instead, I changed the type of test performed by `try_compile` from trying to build an executable to trying to build a static library, by putting this in the toolchain file:

```
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: I think this deserves to be the accepted answer. The real issue is that `try_compile` compiles micro-tests as an iOS Application, which requires code signing. Static libraries do not. I didn't expect this to work, but I was pleasantly surprised!

Comment: That's quite the hack, but the result of try_compile should be an executable, not a library. Using `XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED` to `NO` is more adequate here.

Answer (score 2):

## [Sept 2019] Fix for XCode 11 & iOS 13

As explained [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18993#note_631388).

Need to use `XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED` instead of `CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED` below to make this work:

```
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_PLATFORM_VARIABLES "XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED")
set(XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED "NO")

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

unset(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_PLATFORM_VARIABLES)
unset(XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED)
```

## [Aug 2019]: Info from CMake's issue tracker

The issue was discussed [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18993) and explained by @alcroito. It does not use the custom ios-cmake toolchain but the new [native iOS toolchain](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-ios-tvos-or-watchos) (CMake 3.14+) but the issue is the same.

#### Source of the issue

When using the Xcode generator, it will try to sign applications by default. When looking for `Threads`, CMake calls `FindThreads.cmake` which will call a `TRY_COMPILE` test that Xcode will try to sign and fail at.

#### Proper solution:

Disable signing for the `try_compile` within `FindThreads` (seen [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18993#note_618294)):

```
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_PLATFORM_VARIABLES "CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED")
set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED "NO")

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

unset(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_PLATFORM_VARIABLES)
unset(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED)
```

#### Other solutions in this thread

1. Make the binary of that `try_compile` static, which won't be signed (seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53618014/3783833)). That's not great since it should be an executable and not a static lib.
2. Pass proper information to be able to sign the `try_compile` executable (seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24380608/3783833)). That actually would not work for me.
3. Skip `try_compile` (seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14198386/3783833)): not quite safe since you'll skip all your compiler tests. That would not work for me either.
4. Hardcode `Threads` by overriding what `FindThreads` does (seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32771883/3783833)): quite a dirty workaround.

Comment: Seems that check_cxx_source_compiles also not working without step 1 or 2

Answer (score 1):

You can fix `try_compile` command using next variables in toolchain:

```
# toolchain.cmake    
set(CMAKE_MACOSX_BUNDLE YES)
set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT "iphoneos")
set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "iPhone Developer")
set(MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER "com.example")
```

And minimalistic example:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(Foo)

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
add_executable(foo foo.cpp)
```

Generate output:

```
> cmake -H. -B_builds -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=toolchain.cmake -GXcode
...    
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
...
```

- [Complete solution](https://github.com/ruslo/polly/wiki/Toolchain-list#ios)

Comment: still it Doesn't Work for me.. i am facing Same Error... i am Building log4cplus library for Arm7 Architecture.

Comment: This didn't work for me with CMake 3.14 unfortunately

Answer (score -1):

Just to mention, I also encountered the same problem in my project. I commented out the `find_package(Threads REQUIRED)` line and generate the Xcode proejct. The codes compiled without errors. Maybe Xcode could automatically link with posix thread library.

Answer (score -1):

The solution for me was a combination of the 2 answers before me.
Comment out the 2 lines that disable `try_compile`

```
# Skip the platform compiler checks for cross compiling
set (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)
set (CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)
```

Then add this to the top of the IOS.cmake toolchain file.

```
set(MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example)
set(CMAKE_MACOSX_BUNDLE YES)
set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "iPhone Developer")
```