# finding in packages using cmake find_package

Tags: c, cmake

```
GCC 4.6.0
Linux
cmake 2.8
```

I am using cmake to generate my make file. However, in my `network_imp.c` file I need to do some threading. So I have included the header file `#include <pthread.h>` and I am using the `pthread_create()` function

How can I tell cmake to use this header pthread.h and shared library -lpthread?

I thought about using the find_package, but I don't think I am using it correctly. This is my CMakeLists.txt file.

```
find_package(pthread)

add_library(network SHARED network_imp.c)
```

The error I get when I try and make is this:

```
undefined reference to pthread_create
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: possible duplicate of [cmake and libpthread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620918/cmake-and-libpthread)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you should use `target_link_libraries` cmake command to link your executables with other libraries. `find_package` command is used to set special cmake variables, containing, for example, the actually libraries, to link with.

And for working with `pthread` you should use `find_package(Threads)`.

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620918/cmake-and-libpthread) is the answer to your particular question.

Comment: Hello Beduin, I was just wondering how do I know the name I am looking for. I know I want to find pthreads. But how would I know that it is called Threads? The reason I asked as I am using the apache portable runtime API. And I would like to find the apr package? I tried Apr and APR, but cmake make couldn't find it. Many thanks for any further help.