# How to get CMake to recognize pthread on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, pthreads, cmake, ubuntu-12.10

If I compile on the command-line with g++ directly, I can see everything I need is there:

```
$ g++ -pthread test.cpp
$ ldd a.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd05b3000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f4a1ba8d000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4a1b870000)
    ...more...
```

Then I try to create a simple cmake file for this 5-line test app:

```
$ cat CMakeLists.txt 
PROJECT ( Test CXX )
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED ( VERSION 2.8 )
FIND_PACKAGE ( Threads REQUIRED )
ADD_EXECUTABLE ( test test.cpp )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES ( test ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} )
```

However, I cannot figure out why CMake doesn't find what it needs to use for `Threads`:

```
$ cd build/
$ cmake ..
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find Threads (missing: Threads_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:288 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindThreads.cmake:166 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (FIND_PACKAGE)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Oh, this was was a pain!  I probably lost 2 hours on this.  Here is the solution:

CMake uses short 'C' applications to test/try things.  If the CMakeLists.txt states that C++ is used for the project, without also listing C, then some of those shorts tests incorrectly fail, and cmake then thinks those things aren't found.

The solution was to change the first line of CMakeLists from this:

```
PROJECT ( Test CXX )
```

...to include C as a language:

```
PROJECT ( Test C CXX )
```

Then delete `build`, recreate it, and everything then works:

```
rm -rf build
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

Comment: One has to note that `PROJECT ...` declaration should be stated before the `Find ...` is actually used.

Comment: Did not help me on Ubuntu 20.04 :(

Comment: Did not help me unfortunately, same as any other solution I have found :(