# CMake Error try_compile pthreads of type executable

Tags: c++, pthreads, cmake, fedora

```
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CheckLibraryExists.cmake:41 (try_compile):   Only libraries may be used as try_compile IMPORTED LINK_LIBRARIES.  Got   pthreads of type EXECUTABLE. Call Stack (most recent call first):   /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindThreads.cmake:58 (CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS)   tests/app_suite/CMakeLists.txt:58 (find_package)


-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
```

I'm on fedora 18 64-bit.

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(app_suite_tests ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

is the code that is creating this. What can I do to prevent CMake from throwing an error here, or how can I get CMake to check the pthreads library over the executable?

Thanks.

Additonal Info:

```
if(NOT CMAKE_HAVE_THREADS_LIBRARY)
    # Do we have -lpthreads
    CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS(pthreads pthread_create "" CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREADS_CREATE)
    if(CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREADS_CREATE)
      set(CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT "-lpthreads")
      set(CMAKE_HAVE_THREADS_LIBRARY 1)
      set(Threads_FOUND TRUE)
    endif()
```

Is from FindThreads.cmake, and the error is thrown on CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is specific to cmake 2.8.11+ and a project that has an executable target named "pthreads".  That is the executable that cmake trips over.  Renaming the executable resolves the issue.  See also [the Dr. Memory issue tracker entry on this](https://code.google.com/p/drmemory/issues/detail?id=1264).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(your_executable ${source_files})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(
pthread
)
```

taken from [cmake and libpthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620918/cmake-and-libpthread)

Comment: Not quite I think. CMake is checking for pthread_create in pthreads, and then complaining that pthreads is an executable and not a library. I commented out the pthreads check in FindThreads.cmake, but I then fail a bunch of tests. I think I might be missing something.