# Compilation error prevents definiton of library in CMake, but i can't seem to find the source of it

Tags: makefile, cmake, precompiled-headers, pre-compilation, trinitycore

EDIT: I have found the reason why the plugins library is undefined: it simply fails to compile. That said, i still am having an hard time finding the root cause.

The CMakeError.log outputs this:

```
    Determining if the pthread_create exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/gamemaid/wow/dev/TrinityCore/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTryCompileExec4168097918/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4168097918.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4168097918.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/gamemaid/wow/dev/TrinityCore/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/gamemaid/wow/dev/TrinityCore/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4168097918.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -std=gnu99 -W -Wall -Wextra -Winit-self -Winvalid-pch -Wfatal-errors    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4168097918.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /home/gamemaid/wow/dev/TrinityCore/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec4168097918
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4168097918.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -std=gnu99 -W -Wall -Wextra -Winit-self -Winvalid-pch -Wfatal-errors     CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4168097918.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec4168097918 -rdynamic 

CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4168097918.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o: In function `main':
CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4168097918.dir/build.make:88: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec4168097918' failed
make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec4168097918] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gamemaid/wow/dev/TrinityCore/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec4168097918/fast' failed
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec4168097918/fast] Error 2

File /home/gamemaid/wow/dev/TrinityCore/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
#ifndef pthread_create
  return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}

Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/gamemaid/wow/dev/TrinityCore/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTryCompileExec1876865723/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1876865723.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1876865723.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/gamemaid/wow/dev/TrinityCore/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/gamemaid/wow/dev/TrinityCore/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1876865723.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -std=gnu99 -W -Wall -Wextra -Winit-self -Winvalid-pch -Wfatal-errors -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1876865723.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec1876865723
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1876865723.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -std=gnu99 -W -Wall -Wextra -Winit-self -Winvalid-pch -Wfatal-errors -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1876865723.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec1876865723 -rdynamic -lpthreads 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1876865723.dir/build.make:88: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec1876865723' failed
```

Everything below this line is left for backlog and is no longer part of the issue.

> I have been beating my head on this CMake code for days, to no avail.
>   For some reason, by the time i call it on
>
> ```
> if (USE_COREPCH) add_cxx_pch(plugins ${plugins_STAT_PCH_HDR} ${plugins_STAT_PCH_SRC}) endif()
> ```
>
> the variable "plugins" is undefined, and the method fails. I can't
>   seem to understand why this is the case, since i clearly define it
>   with the add_library method.
>
> ```
>     CollectSourceFiles(
>   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
>   PRIVATE_SOURCES
>   # Exclude
>   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/pch)
>
>
> if (USE_COREPCH)
>   set(plugins_STAT_PCH_HDR pch/pch.h)
>   set(plugins_STAT_PCH_SRC pch/pch.cpp)
> endif ()
>
> GroupSources(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
>
> add_library(plugins STATIC
>   ${plugins_STAT_PCH_SRC}
>   ${PRIVATE_SOURCES}
> )
>
> CollectIncludeDirectories(
>   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
>   PUBLIC_INCLUDES
>   # Exclude
>   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/pch)
>
> target_include_directories(plugins
>   PUBLIC
>     ${PUBLIC_INCLUDES}
>   PRIVATE
>     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
>
> add_dependencies(plugins revision_data.h)
>
> if( WIN32 )
>   if ( MSVC )
>   add_custom_command(TARGET plugins
>       POST_BUILD
>     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/playerbot/aiplayerbot.conf.dist.in
> ```
>
> ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/$(ConfigurationName)/
>           )
>         add_custom_command(TARGET plugins
>             POST_BUILD
>           COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ahbot/ahbot.conf.dist.in
>   ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/$(ConfigurationName)/
>           )
>         elseif ( MINGW )
>
> ```
>    add_custom_command(TARGET plugins
>       POST_BUILD
>       COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}playerbot/aiplayerbot.conf.dist.in
> ```
>
> ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/
>           )
>         add_custom_command(TARGET plugins
>             POST_BUILD
>             COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}ahbot/ahbot.conf.dist.in
>   ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/
>           )
>         endif()
>       endif()
>
> ```
> if( UNIX )
>   install(TARGETS plugins DESTINATION bin)
>   install(FILES playerbot/aiplayerbot.conf.dist.in DESTINATION ${CONF_DIR})
>   install(FILES ahbot/ahbot.conf.dist.in DESTINATION ${CONF_DIR})
> elseif( WIN32 )
>   install(TARGETS plugins DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")
>   install(FILES playerbot/aiplayerbot.conf.dist.in DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")
>   install(FILES ahbot/ahbot.conf.dist.in DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")
> endif()
>
>
> # DEBUG CODE
> if (DEFINED plugins)
> MESSAGE("PLUGINS IS DEFINED")
> endif()
> MESSAGE(${plugins_STAT_PCH_SRC})
> MESSAGE(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
> MESSAGE(${PRIVATE_SOURCES})
> # DEBUG
>
> if (USE_COREPCH)
>   add_cxx_pch(plugins ${plugins_STAT_PCH_HDR} ${plugins_STAT_PCH_SRC})
> endif()
> ```
>
> EDIT: I have confirmed that immediately after the add_library(plugins
>   [..]) call plugins is still undefined. This is really weird and i have
>   no idea what to do about it.

Comment: `plugins` is not a *variable*, it is a **target**. These are different concepts in CMake.

Comment: Previous versions of the question are stored in the *revision history*. No needs to save irrelevant things in the question post just for "backlog".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmake and libpthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620918/cmake-and-libpthread)