# Undefined Boost Thread Reference when Compiling Caffe Code

Tags: boost, cmake, caffe

I have installed Boost 1.63.0 locally, as well as Caffe (version rc3). I am currently trying to compile some Caffe code using CMake, but I get the following linker error:

```
/home/local/boost_1_63_0/boost/thread/pthread/once_atomic.hpp:145:
undefined reference to `boost::thread_detail::enter_once_region(boost::once_flag&)'

/home/local/boost_1_63_0/boost/thread/pthread/once_atomic.hpp:157:
undefined reference to `boost::thread_detail::commit_once_region(boost::once_flag&)'

/home/local/boost_1_63_0/boost/thread/pthread/once_atomic.hpp:153: 
undefined reference to `boost::thread_detail::rollback_once_region(boost::once_flag&)'

libcpp_stuff_library.a(Log.cpp.o): In function `logging::get_log()':
/home/local/boost_1_63_0/boost/thread/pthread/once_atomic.hpp:145: 
undefined reference to `boost::thread_detail::enter_once_region(boost::once_flag&)'

/home/local/boost_1_63_0/boost/thread/pthread/once_atomic.hpp:157: 
undefined reference to `boost::thread_detail::commit_once_region(boost::once_flag&)'

/home/local/boost_1_63_0/boost/thread/pthread/once_atomic.hpp:153: 
undefined reference to `boost::thread_detail::rollback_once_region(boost::once_flag&)'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My first thought is that I'm somehow linking to Boost the wrong way in my CMake file. Right now, in CMakeLists.txt, I have:

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "/home/local/boost_1_63_0")
find_package( Boost 1.6.3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem system thread )
```

My second thought was that this had something to do with pthreads, so I linked to pthreads in my CMakeLists.txt using this StackOverflow answer: [cmake and libpthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620918/cmake-and-libpthread). However, I still get the same error after doing this.

Does anyone have other suggestions about what might be the problem here? Thank you.

Comment: Have you Cmake >= 3.7? cf http://stackoverflow.com/q/42123509/2799037

Comment: Yes, I have CMake version 2.8.12.2. Good thought, though.

Comment: That's the problem!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake finds Boost but the imported targets not available for Boost version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123509/cmake-finds-boost-but-the-imported-targets-not-available-for-boost-version)

Comment: Alright, I locally installed CMake 3.8 and used that, but I'm still having the same problem. I've tried this with Boost version 1.60, 1.61 and 1.63 (I've also tried the older version of CMake - 2.8 - with all three of these Boost versions). Each time, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling `Caffe` using a locally installed `Boost 1.63`, source code build, with `CMake 3.7`, I've run into a similar issues.  The `Caffe 1.0` `CMake` folder contains `Dependencies.cmake` and `Caffe` is looking for `Boost 1.45` not `Boost 1.62` or `Boost 1.63` and `Python 3.5.3` `Ubuntu 17.04` launchpad distribution files.  The locally installed file `libboost_python.so` or `libboost_python.so.1.63.0` in folder `/usr/local/lib` are differently named from the launchpad distribution files in folder `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` `libboost_python-py35.so`.