# Using CMakeLists causes error while compiling fine in commandline

Tags: gcc, cmake, posix, clion

I am compiling my code, in which I use posix threads in C.

I am using CLion and its CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(Test)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
add_definitions(-lpthread)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)

add_executable(Test ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

I am getting errors (eg: `undefined reference to`sem_init'`).

The proposed suggestion for solution is adding `-lpthread` compiler flag, but I already added it.

I compiled the same code from commandline:

```
gcc main.c -lpthread
```

It compiles without any problem.

What can be a possible problem/solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmake and libpthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620918/cmake-and-libpthread)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `add_definitions(-lpthread)` entirely since pthread is not a definition, but a library dependency.

Add after `add_executable()`:

```
target_link_libraries(Test pthread)
```

Also, if you want to see what commands CMake is using without having to examine its files, you can use it on the command line with `cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON ...`.

Btw, always prefer all the `target_*` commands, like `target_compile_definitions()` instead of older style `add_definitions()`. This keeps your project properties and dependencies clean and minimizes interference between different targets.

If after the above changes your code still does not compile, then it is highly likely the code itself is wrong (nothing to do with CMake).