# How do I determine which cmake package contains a desired static library?

Tags: cmake

I have some legacy code (building against the mysql embedded server library) which contains a link line that looks like this:

```
 -L/usr/local/lib -lmysqld -lm -ldl -lcrypt -lpthread
```

I know that I can get a list of supported cmake modules with `cmake --help-module-list`, but how do know which modules contains the libraries libm.a, libdl.a, etc.?

I know that I could use `link_directories(/usr/local/lib)` to specify that location, and just put -lm, -ldl, etc. into my `target_link_libraries` command, but the docs seem to discourage that - that using `find_library` or `find_package` is desirable.

I can probably muddle through putting together something with find_library that will work with all our target platforms, but if these libraries are already defined in an existing package, I think that would be the most desirable way to do it.

So, the general question is: given some known libraries, how to I locate the relevant cmake package that contains them?

EDIT:  There seems to be some confusion about what I'm asking.  I understand that `find_package` doesn't actually "contain" the libraries, but it serves as platform-independent way of locating the libraries for common configurations.  For example, in my case above, I found in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620918/cmake-and-libpthread) that I could deal with the pthread library by using this construction:

```
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(my_app Threads::Threads)
```

But how was I supposed to know this?  Is there a way I can discover this for myself without asking SO questions and hoping someone can answer it for me?   And what should I use for the other libraries (m, dl, crypt, etc.).

Comment: What is a "cmake package" and should there be one at all? Looks more like an OS/installation than programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

> given some known libraries, how to I locate the relevant cmake package that contains them?

If corresponded CMake package exists, it usually has a name similar to the name of the library.

Note, that *CMake package* is **not a container** for a library (like distro packages are, e.g. `mysql-devel`). *CMake package* is simply a **script**, which *finds* a library.

Absence of the script doesn't mean absence of the library itself; it means .. that no one has writen such script. Nothing more.