# Undefined reference to pthread CLion

Tags: c++, c++11, pthreads, clion

I'm trying to run this simple thread c++ program in CLion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;


//Start of the thread t1
 void hello() {
     cout << "Hello,concurrent world!" << endl; }



 int main() {
     thread t1(hello);     // spawn new thread that calls hello()

     cout << "Concurrency has started!" << endl;
     t1.join();            

     cout << "Concurrency completed!";

     return 0;
   }
```

My problem is that there's an error of undefined reference to pthread, and I don't undestand what I'm doing wrong... please notice that I'm  doing this on CLion.

Comment: You need to link with `-lpthread`.

Comment: @Sam ... or even better with `-pthread`.

Comment: It's much better to use cross-platform style, listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4774027/3315622

Answer (score 25):

In CLion, to compile with flag -pthread you should add the following line to CMakeLists.txt (I've tested and it works):

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -pthread)
```

Comment: It worked for me but I also had to add `find_package(Threads)`.

Comment: @PaulLaffitte It worked for me without having to add `find_package(Threads)`

Comment: I downvoted not because this is a bad answer, it was ok at the time of writing. However, best practice is now to use `find_package(…)` and link against `Threads::Threads` as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58052624/2299084

Answer (score 5):

In `CMake` first find the package:

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
```

Then link against it:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Threads::Threads)
```

Now the build will succeed the linking step.

Comment: Best "modern" cmake answer, thx!

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile with flag `-lpthread` or `-pthread` (its usually advised to use`pthread`). If you're using CLion then you will need to edit CMakeLists.txt to ensure that your code is compiled with this flag by setting compiler flags with a command like:

```
SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "<other compiler flags> -pthread")
```

You can learn more about these options on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling).

Comment: with `-pthread` flag? First I hear about that. Where you found that information?

Comment: I learned about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling

Comment: As the answer in the linked question states, you should use -pthread, not -lpthread.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are linking to pthread in the end of your CMakeLists.txt

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} pthread)
```

Comment: That is not enough. You also have to set the compiler flag `-pthread`

Answer (score 0):

As per CLion 2021.3.3, no need to specify any additional settings:

Simply be sure to start from C and not C++ and select C 99.

--

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(threads01 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(threads01 main.c)
```