# How do I get CMake to dynamically link a merged static library with system libraries?

Tags: merge, cmake, cuda, static-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have to merge one of my app's libs with the NVIDIA CUDA static lib using this horrific awful CMake code:

```
GET_TARGET_PROPERTY(OUTPUT_LIB ${LIBNAME} LOCATION)
add_custom_command (TARGET ${LIBNAME}
                    POST_BUILD
                    COMMAND mv ${OUTPUT_LIB} ${OUTPUT_LIB}.old
                    COMMAND echo "create ${OUTPUT_LIB}" > combineLibs.mri
                    COMMAND echo "addlib ${OUTPUT_LIB}.old" >> combineLibs.mri
                    COMMAND echo "addlib ${CUDA_LOCATION}"  >> combineLibs.mri
                    COMMAND echo "save"  >> combineLibs.mri
                    COMMAND echo "end" >> combineLibs.mri
                    COMMAND ar -M <combineLibs.mri
                    COMMAND rm ${OUTPUT_LIB}.old
                    COMMENT "Building merged library for ${LIBNAME} at ${OUTPUT_LIB}, including ${CUDA_LOCATION}"
)
target_link_libraries(${LIBNAME} -pthread -c)
```

This successfully produces a merged static library that has all the symbols in it. However, the NVIDIA CUDA static lib brought with it dependencies on libpthread and libc in the form of unresolved symbols. Now the merged library also has those unresolved symbols, and the `target_link_libraries` line doesn't seem to do what I seem to think it does, because the symbols don't get resolved at link-time. How do I get the merged static library to dynamically link against libpthread and libc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `the target_link_libraries` line does indeed not do what you think.

`target_link_libraries(`*target*`,`*options*`)` can have the desired effect of
adding the linker options *options* to the linkage of *target* only if *target*
is something that is produced by the linker. If no linkage happens in the
production of *target* then this directive will have no effect.

Your target is a static library. A static library - unlike a program, and unlike
a dynamic/shared library - is not produced by the linker. As your `custom_command`
in fact illustrates, a static library is produced by the GNU general purpose archiver,
`ar`. It is nothing but an archive of files which happen to be object files,
but as far as `ar` is concerned they might as well be the contents of your
Documents, Pictures and Music folders. Since no linkage is involved in the
production of a static library, nothing can be linked with a static library.

An `ar` archive can be used as a linker *input* in the linkage of something that
*is* produced by the linker - a program or a shared library. In that case the
linker will look into the archive to see if contains any object files it needs
to carry on the linkage. If it finds any, it will extract them from the archive
and link *them* into the program. The linkage will be exactly the same as if
you had listed the required object files in the linker commandline and not
mentioned the archive at all.

But if any of the object files that the linker extracts from an archive bring
with them undefined references, then to get them resolved you must link some
library or libraries that define those references *in the linkage of the
program or shared library that you want the linker to produce* - just as you
must do to resolve undefined references in any other object files you
input to the linkage.

So,

> How do I get the merged static library to dynamically link against libpthread and libc?

You can't. It doesn't make sense. Any library dependencies of object files
in a static library can be satisfied only in the linkage of a *program or shared library*
that has acquired those dependencies by linking those object files.

Finally, `-c` is not a GCC linkage option that will have the effect of requesting
linkage of `libc`. It is not a linkage option at all. It is an option that
directs the GCC frontend *not* to invoke the linker. It is passed to GCC to
request compilation without linkage, and the perverse effect of including it in a
CMake `target_link_libraries` directive will be to stop any linkage of the
target from happening.

If you want to explicitly request linkage of `libc`, use `-lc`, following
the linker usage protocol that `-lname` requests linkage of `libname`.

Perhaps you inferred that `-c` requests linkage of `libc` from the assumption
that `-pthread` requests linkage of `libpthread`. In fact, `-lpthread` would
request linkage of `libpthread`. The option `-pthread` is a more abstract GCC
option, for both compilation and linkage, that means *do the right things, for this platform, to link with the Posix Threads
library* - which might entail passing `-lpthead` to the linker, and possibly not.

Thus `-pthread` *is* OK as an argument of `target_link_libraries` that will
have the effect of requesting Posix Threads linkage, but see
answers to [cmake and libpthread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1620918/1362568)
for CMake-proper ways of doing this.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful.