# undefined reference to `pthread_create' CLion

Tags: linux, cmake, clion

I'm trying to compile my program using CLion under Linux (Ubuntu) OS.

My CMake file:

```
# cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
  project(untitled2 C)

  set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -pthread)
  add_executable(untitled2 main.c)
```

My pragram using threads so ***I've added*** `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -pthread)` that required to compile my program.
I got a compilation error: "undefined reference to pthread_create"

I can compile the program via the terminal using the following:

```
gcc main.c -o main -pthread
```

I think that my issue is with the CMake file. 
Can someone please help my with that matter ?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to pass `-pthread` to the *linker* as well (or explicitly link with `-lpthread`). You might also want to read about [the CMake `FindThreads` funciton](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindThreads.html) (though it's offline at the moment, will come back soon according to their page).

Comment: Oh by the way, `CXX` anything is for C++, not C.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I Changed CXX to C and the compilation completed successfully!

Comment: How do you set the **C** standard to be used (even if it's added automatically by CLion)? There's a very simple pattern regarding languages and related variables in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmake and libpthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620918/cmake-and-libpthread)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I might still not be the best option but using a call to
`find_package(Threads REQUIRED)`
in combination with
`target_link_libraries(mytarget PRIVATE Threads::Threads)`
is the more modern way of getting to your goal because you should perform your actions on a target (instead of using 'magic' variables that could influence other parts of the project or even contain spelling issues).

See: https://codingnest.com/basic-cmake-part-2/

Answer (score 9):

You have to change  `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -pthread)` in `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS -pthread)`, because *CXX* stay for C++. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to CMakeLists works fine for me:

```
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(myprog Threads::Threads )
```