# CMake check_symbol_exists doesn't work because of missing -pthread

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, pthreads

I'm trying to build https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace.git on Ubuntu 18.04.  I built and installed its dependency `bcc` by hand (the bpftrace repo build docs suggest that because the packaged version on ubuntu lacks required header files).

I found that cmake would complain for me as follows:

```
-- Looking for bcc_prog_load - not found
```

After some `CMakeLists.txt` edits to ensure suitable `-I` flags are passed, and looking in `CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log`, I see that the build fails like this:

```
/usr/bin/cc  -I/home/me/dev/bcc/src/cc -I/home/me/dev/bcc/src/cc/libbpf/src   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_653d8.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /home/me/dev/bpftrace/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_653d8
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_653d8.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc      -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_653d8.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o  -o cmTC_653d8 -lbcc 
CMakeFiles/cmTC_653d8.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o: In function `main':
CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I run with `--debug-trycompile` and run the failing commands by hand, I see that passing the `-pthread` command line option to gcc fixes that error.  From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29871891) I glean that something like the following is supposed to fix that:

```
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(my_app Threads::Threads)
```

However, the thing that is failing here is not some target I have added, but merely a check for the presence of a symbol:

```
check_symbol_exists(bcc_prog_load "libbpf.h" HAVE_BCC_PROG_LOAD)
```

I therefore don't know how to specify a target for `target_link_libraries`.  I tried replacing the `target_link_libraries` with `link_libraries` (dropping the first argument `my_app`), but that does not cause CMake to pass the `-pthread` argument to gcc when testing for the presence of the symbol.

What can I do to make the `check_symbol_exists` work?

Comment: You may set variable `CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES` with additional libraries for link when use `check_symbol_exists`. See more in the documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckSymbolExists.html.

Comment: @Tsyvarev if I add pthread to that list, it does get past this, thanks!  Now I immediately hit another problem that it's not passing `-L` with the appropriate directory :-( and nothing I try makes it pass that (not `link_directories("/absolute/path/to/lib")`, nor `set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_LINK_OPTIONS "-L/absolute/path/to/lib")`)

Comment: Why do you need `-L` option for `check_symbol_exists`? Or do you have `pthreads` installed locally?

Comment: That -L is for the library whose symbol I'm checking exists (bcc), which yes, is installed locally @Tsyvarev

Comment: Hm, passing `-L` option via `CMAKE_REQUIRED_LINK_OPTIONS` variable should work. As last resort, in the `CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES` variable you may use **absolute path** to your library instead of library's name.