# I have to run cmake twice for compile the project

Tags: c++, multithreading, makefile, cmake, pthreads

I got the following error with the first running of the command

```
cmake .
```

But if I run the command again, the compilation succeed. That is, I have to run `cmake` **twice** for make the project compiled. Why is it so? How could I fix it?

**Error message**:

```
CMakeFiles/exec.dir/Timer.cpp.o: In function `std::thread::thread<Timer::Timer()::{lambda()#1}>(Timer::Timer()::{lambda()#1}&&)':
/usr/include/c++/7/thread:122: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/exe.dir/build.make:146: recipe for target 'exe' failed
make[2]: *** [exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/exe.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/exe.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread -g -std=c++14 -std=c++11 -std=c++17 ")

project(myproject)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Timer.cpp TimerEntity.cpp)
add_executable(exe ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: Are you sure -pthread should be in compilation flags? Missing references are link time errors, and external libraries are pointles at the point of compilation into object file.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620918/cmake-and-libpthread. That question describes working with pthreads in CMake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not usually noted, but appending compiler flags via

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} <...>")
```

should be placed **after** the `project()` call.

Exactly `project()` call sets the initial value of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable.

Normally, `project()` call is issued just after the `cmake_minimum_required()`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(437_Hw1)

...
```

#### Details

In your current code, when you call `cmake` the first time, your first setting `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ...)` is replaced by the value of the following `project()` call and stored in the **CACHE**.

When you call `cmake` the second time, `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable is already set (it is loaded from the *cache*). So, `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ...)` sets the variable to correct value. Moreover, following `project()` doesn't change `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable because it finds it already in the cache.

Answer (score 3):

I reworked your CMakeLists.txt to use modern CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(437_Hw1)

# CMake can set the standard in a cross-platform way for you
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp SubTimer.cpp TimerEntity.cpp)
add_executable(exe ${SOURCE_FILES})

# These two lines add the platform-specific magic for the right threading library/headers.
find_package(Threads)
target_link_libraries(exe Threads::Threads)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you replace the line

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread -g -std=c++14 -std=c++11 -std=c++17 ")
```

with

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
target_link_libraries(exe pthread)
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: you are saying. I cannot use on windows ? So, how could i use thread? If I write in ubuntu then in order to work on windows.

Comment: Then you will need a wrapper interface for the windows threads libraries. You could write your own using the windows API, or preferably one that is already there, like boost or qt.

Comment: @herobee1965 Use `std::thread` (part of the C++11 standard and up) instead of `pthread` (Unix library that implements threads)

Comment: @Botje I use std::thread but when i compile. I need to put pthread?

Comment: That is true, on Linux you need to specifically link to pthread when using `std::thread`, the linker will not do this for you. I don't know what it gives on Windows. Maybe no need to link to anything at all ?