# Why is there a distinction between linking with target object libraries and libraries using add_library and add_executable?

Tags: c++, cmake

This is my simple `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project(MyProject)

# Create the library from server.cpp
add_library(server OBJECT tcp_server.cpp tcp_server_priv.cpp)
# Add the current directory to the include path for this target
target_include_directories(server PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# Create the executable from main.cpp and link it to the library
add_executable(my_server main.cpp $<TARGET_OBJECTS:server>)
```

I recently learned about the `add_library(x OBJECT y z ...)` construct; my understanding: this doesn't create a static or shared library (.a or .so), but rather forms some temporary/logical grouping of object files, which can be referenced elsewhere as that same group. I.e. elsewhere, I can refer to `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:server>` to refer to *tcp_server.o* and *tcp_server_priv.o* in aggregate, so the line `add_executable(my_server main.cpp $<TARGET_OBJECTS:server>)` means "compile main.cpp, and link it with *tcp_server.o* and *tcp_server_priv.o* to make the executable *my_server*".

I.e. the `add_executable` line does both compiling and linking.

I wanted my executable to also link with *libpthread*, so I tried making this change to the `add_executable` line:

```
add_executable(my_server main.cpp $<TARGET_OBJECTS:server> pthread)
```

...but that generated this error with *cmake*:

```
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:9 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    pthread

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:9 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: med_server


CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
make: *** [Makefile:160: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

Isn't the above analogous to the following, where I compile *main.cpp*, link object-file dependencies, and libraries in a single `g++` invocation:

```
// tcp_server.cpp
#include <iostream>

extern void private_func();

void public_func() {
  std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  private_func();
}
```

```
// tcp_server_priv.cpp
#include <iostream>

void private_func() {
  std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
```

```
// main.cpp
#include <semaphore.h>

extern void public_func();

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  sem_t my_sem;

  public_func();
  sem_init(&my_sem, 0, 0);
  sem_destroy(&my_sem);

  return 0;
}
```

```
$ g++ -c ./tcp_server.cpp \
> && g++ -c ./tcp_server_priv.cpp \
> && g++ main.cpp tcp_server.o tcp_server_priv.o -lpthread \
> && ./a.out
public_func
private_func
$
```

?

**Why can I not link a library with the `add_executable` statement when I can link object files?**

Isn't the attempted `add_executable(my_server main.cpp $<TARGET_OBJECTS:server> pthread)` effectively the same as `g++ main.cpp tcp_server.o tcp_server_priv.o -lpthread`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TLDR: The distinction is more apparent when you realize what the compilation process looks like.

EDIT: [Link to compilation models for better understanding](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjimfawcett.github.io%2FCppModels.html&psig=AOvVaw0gK5jOm_ZV5xy1BqNc-MA0&ust=1675323453974000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCOjCwq3o8_wCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAi), NOTE: you're interested [just in the first picture](https://jimfawcett.github.io/Pictures/CompilationModel.JPG).

---

For this example I will use a static library, i.e. on linux it would be suffixed with `.a` on windows `.lib`. Let's ask ourselves what happens when you build and link this library:

- The steps before are not important for the distinction, so let's start with the following step
- The compiler compiles the individual `.cpp` (or multiple) into `.o` object files
- These files are then **linked together / archived** into a library `.a` / `.lib`

Now if we want to "link" a **static** library:

- We will actually unpack this archive `.a` back into the object files
- We will then grab the `.o` object files that we compiled in our executable
- Compiler does some optimizations and throws out unwanted object files
- Repacks and links all **the remaining object files** we have, into an executable

---

So you can think of the distinction as such (using static library as an example):

**Object files**: We don't have to unpack the archive, we just need to link them with the newly created object files

**Static library**: We need to tell the compiler that hey, we need to unpack this first so we can link it.

The only role of CMake is to "create some sort of a configuration" for your compiler/linker in order to get the job done.

---

One interesting thing about the distinction  between `OBJECT` and `STATIC` libraries is ( which further demonstrates what I mentioned ) is that if you use `OBJECT` libraries you will not take advantage of optimization.

Suppose your static library is constructed of three objects `a.o` `b.o` and `c.o`. If you pack it into `lib.a` and then link your executable against it. The optimization might exclude `c.o` (for example) and this will make the resulting executable smaller.

**BUT** if you link with object libraries  `a.o` `b.o` and `c.o` then *all* of the objects will be packed with the executable.

Comment: In case you are available for a follow-up discussion: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251557/room-for-stonethrow-and-milan-s -- but don't feel obliged, and thank you for this answer.

Comment: @StoneThrow sure thing, I've joined the chat and will check it here and there (mostly at night GMT+1)

Answer (score 1):

In your

```
add_executable(my_server main.cpp $<TARGET_OBJECTS:server> pthread)
```

, the problem is with the usage of "pthread" in `add_executable`- not `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:server>`. You should be doing this to link to pthread:

```
target_link_libraries(my_server PRIVATE pthread)
```

or

```
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(my_app PRIVATE Threads::Threads)
```

See also: [cmake and libpthread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1620918/11107541) and [the CMake object library docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries).

As stated in the object library docs, this is just how CMake works. You can link to object libraries like you are doing, but you can also do it via `target_link_libraries`. You can use `target_link_libraries` to link to both object libraries (since v3.12) and shared/static libraries. With respect to `target_link_libraries`, there is no "distinction".

Comment: Can you speak a little about this "distinction" between why you are able to link _object libraries_ with the `add_executable` statement, but you cannot link _libraries_? In my mind, I keep trying to "equate" what CMake is doing with a _g++_ statement...so it "appears" to me that the `add_executable` statement can be translated to `g++ a.cpp b.o c.o` but cannot be translated to `g++ a.cpp b.o c.o -lsome_lib`...it just feels like an artificial distinction that I'm having trouble justifying in my mind.

Comment: "That's just the way CMake is" is a perfectly acceptable answer -- I just wanted to know/learn either way. :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's just the way CMake is. It might be due to historical reasons, as I just edited to say that linking object libraries via target_link_libraries became a thing in v3.12. To get a real official answer, you're best asking the CMake maintainers, which you can do on discourse.cmake.org.

Comment: "I'm pretty sure that's just the way CMake is." - this makes absolute no sense in this context.

Comment: @StoneThrow there definitely was a distinction in mind when doing this. The fact that creating "`OBJECT` libraries" is a new feature is not related to this. "user" explained how to link - his answer is half right in this context. I've created an answer that explains it from the perspective of the actual compilation process. [Take a look here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjimfawcett.github.io%2FCppModels.html&psig=AOvVaw0gK5jOm_ZV5xy1BqNc-MA0&ust=1675323453974000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCOjCwq3o8_wCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAi) - it will make more sense