How to privately link a library to an external static library with CMake
I have a library B that privately depends on an external static library A.
I would like library B to statically link to library A such that any library that links to library B then doesn't need to link to library A; and even library to be hidden outside of library B.
Here is a minimal example.
A/A.hpp
namespace A
{

int A();

}

A/A.cpp
include "A.hpp"

using namespace A;

int A::A()
{
    return 1;
}

I get A.a with
g++ -c A.cpp
ar rvs A.a A.o

Now A.a is considered as an external library.
B/B.hpp
amespace B
{

int B();

}

B/B.cpp
#include "B.hpp"

#include "A.hpp"

using namespace B;

int B::B()
{
    return A::A();
}

B/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15.0)

project(B LANGUAGES CXX)

add_library(A STATIC IMPORTED)
target_include_directories(A INTERFACE ../A)
set_target_properties(A PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../A/A.a)

add_library(B_B)
target_sources(B_B PRIVATE B.cpp)
target_link_libraries(B_B PRIVATE A)

add_executable(B_main)
target_sources(B_main PRIVATE main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(B_main PUBLIC B_B)

Now If I run
cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
cmake --build build --config Release -- VERBOSE=1


-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.3.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (0.1s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/XXX/test/B/build

/home/XXX/Programmes/cmake-3.29.2-linux-x86_64/bin/cmake -S/home/XXX/test/B -B/home/XXX/test/B/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/home/XXX/Programmes/cmake-3.29.2-linux-x86_64/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/XXX/test/B/build/CMakeFiles /home/XXX/test/B/build//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
gmake[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « /home/XXX/test/B/build »
/usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/B_B.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/B_B.dir/depend
gmake[2] : on entre dans le répertoire « /home/XXX/test/B/build »
cd /home/XXX/test/B/build && /home/XXX/Programmes/cmake-3.29.2-linux-x86_64/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/XXX/test/B /home/XXX/test/B /home/XXX/test/B/build /home/XXX/test/B/build /home/XXX/test/B/build/CMakeFiles/B_B.dir/DependInfo.cmake "--color="
gmake[2] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/XXX/test/B/build »
/usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/B_B.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/B_B.dir/build
gmake[2] : on entre dans le répertoire « /home/XXX/test/B/build »
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/B_B.dir/B.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++  -isystem /home/XXX/test/B/../A -O3 -DNDEBUG -MD -MT CMakeFiles/B_B.dir/B.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/B_B.dir/B.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/B_B.dir/B.cpp.o -c /home/XXX/test/B/B.cpp
[ 50%] Linking CXX static library libB_B.a
/home/XXX/Programmes/cmake-3.29.2-linux-x86_64/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/B_B.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
/home/XXX/Programmes/cmake-3.29.2-linux-x86_64/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/B_B.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/ar qc libB_B.a CMakeFiles/B_B.dir/B.cpp.o
/usr/bin/ranlib libB_B.a
gmake[2] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/XXX/test/B/build »
[ 50%] Built target B_B
/usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/B_main.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/B_main.dir/depend
gmake[2] : on entre dans le répertoire « /home/XXX/test/B/build »
cd /home/XXX/test/B/build && /home/XXX/Programmes/cmake-3.29.2-linux-x86_64/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/XXX/test/B /home/XXX/test/B /home/XXX/test/B/build /home/XXX/test/B/build /home/XXX/test/B/build/CMakeFiles/B_main.dir/DependInfo.cmake "--color="
gmake[2] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/XXX/test/B/build »
/usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/B_main.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/B_main.dir/build
gmake[2] : on entre dans le répertoire « /home/XXX/test/B/build »
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/B_main.dir/main.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -O3 -DNDEBUG -MD -MT CMakeFiles/B_main.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/B_main.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/B_main.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/XXX/test/B/main.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable B_main
/home/XXX/Programmes/cmake-3.29.2-linux-x86_64/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/B_main.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++ -O3 -DNDEBUG CMakeFiles/B_main.dir/main.cpp.o -o B_main  libB_B.a /home/XXX/test/B/../A/A.a
gmake[2] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/XXX/test/B/build »
[100%] Built target B_main
gmake[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/XXX/test/B/build »
/home/XXX/Programmes/cmake-3.29.2-linux-x86_64/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/XXX/test/B/build/CMakeFiles 0


In particular, the compilation of the main executable includes the dependency to library A:
/usr/bin/c++ -O3 -DNDEBUG CMakeFiles/B_main.dir/main.cpp.o -o B_main  libB_B.a /home/XXX/test/B/../A/A.a

Is there a way to avoid this?

If both library A and library B are static then you must specify them both in the final linker command line, regardless of whether you are linking a dynamic library or an executable.

@trojanfoe so is there no way to hide library A from the other libraries depending on B?

The only way I can think of is to merge the two libraries, given static libraries are just archives of object files (.o).

Is this a case for making A an OBJECT library? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75305718/why-is-there-a-distinction-between-linking-with-target-object-libraries-and-libr

Cmake is just a build system. It sets up your build using specified toolchain, the toolchain still handles actual compilation and linking. When you link anything with A, you will need to include A in linker command, whether as a separate library or archived together with others. You can try to archive A into B_B, which would hide everything - as long as you truly never link with both A and B_B.
