CMake - Set compile flag for singular file in project
I have a C++ file in a project that uses multithreading and I can't compile it without adding the compiler flag "-pthread". I am compiling using CMake and want to add the flag for only this one file.
The "setup" is:
add_executable(someClass thisClass.cpp)
The one solution that works is set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread") but I understand this is bad practice.
Other things I have seen and tried that didn't work are:
target_compile_options(someClass PRIVATE -pthread)
set_target_properties(someClass PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS -pthread)
I am not super familar with CMake so I don't know if quotations actually do much but I have also tried adding quotations around -pthread.
For these other solutions, I know they don't work because the build fails and because I run it with
make VERBOSE=1 and don't see the flag being passed to the compiler.
Thanks for your time and help!

target_compile_options should add the flag for the compiler. Probably, you inspect the command line for the linker, that command line is actually not affected by target_compile_options. But if you want to add pthread support, why do not search specifically for it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620918/cmake-and-libpthread
